# How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, ssl-certificate, app-transport-security

I have the following simple code to connect to a SSL webpage

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequest returningResponse: nil error: &error ];
```

Except it gives an error if the cert is a self signed one `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 UserInfo=0xd29930 "untrusted server certificate".` Is there a way to set it to accept connections anyway (just like in a browser you can press accept) or a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 419, accepted):

There is a supported API for accomplishing this! Add something like this to your `NSURLConnection` delegate:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
  return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
      [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

  [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Note that `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` can send its message to challenge.sender (much) later, after presenting a dialog box to the user if necessary, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. Just remove the the two ifs and keep only the useCendential part in the didReceiveAuthentificationChallenge callback if you want to accept any https site.

Comment: This is awesome! However, it only works on iPhone and 10.6.  Is there a similar work-around for 10.5?

Comment: Any thoughts on how to send a authenticated credential (created with "credentialWithUser") along with this "credentialForTrust" credential? Specifically...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949640/nsurlconnection-nsurlrequest-untrusted-cert-and-user-authentication

Comment: what is a trustedHosts, where n how is the object defined

Comment: Ameya, it would be an NSArray of NSString objects. The strings are the host names like @"google.com".

Comment: This code works well.  But note that the entire point of having valid certificates is to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks. So be aware if you use this code, someone can spoof the so-called "trusted host".

You still get the data encryption features of SSL but you lose the host identify validation features.

Comment: Keep in mind that, without additional code, this approach will also check against valid certs.

Comment: For those using Gowalla's [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking) library, you can get this feature by pasting that code at the bottom of [AFURLConnectionOperation.m](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L387)

Comment: Works well. Just added the domain of my server to the trustedServers array and bang. Funnily enough the issue only arose on the iPhone 3G

Comment: how can this be applied with sendAsynchronousRequest (as we cannot set a delegate for that one)?

Comment: Just want to chime in that these delegate methods aren't called on the sendSynchronous class method.   See: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679944/objective-c-ssl-synchronous-connection)

Comment: These methods are now considered deprecated as of iOS 5.0 and Mac OS X 10.6. The `-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` method should be used instead.

Comment: true but the older methods will still be called "If connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge: is not implemented, the older, deprecated methods connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:, connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:, and connection:didCancelAuthenticationChallenge: are called instead."

Comment: I surround this kind of code with #ifdef DEBUG/#endif so that it doesn't end up in production.  Would be nice to see a version that works using non-deprecated code.

Comment: @Gordon If I am using [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request] how can I achieve the same output? Its not possible to change it to asynchronous now.

Comment: @Gordon...What dialog box are you talking about..is it that "connection is not secure" or "not valid certificate"...Please help me as want to certificate validation in my iOS code.Where should i place that dialog box in   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

Comment: @AndrewR. When I add that line I get two errors, one saying that it expects to see (, and another saying it expects to see ). You said I'm supposed to add it to the NSURLRequest delegate, but I only have the delegate for the project itself, am I confusing something here?

Comment: @AndrewR. It seems like you have to add a "- " to the beginning of that method, and an empty body.

Comment: This does not help if you are trying to use MPMoviePlayerController.  I have no problem in the simulator but does not work on the iPhone itself.

Comment: Is there a solution for those using the class method +sendAsync...?

Comment: I have implemented the delegate methods but why aren't they being called?

Comment: @jsetting32 may be you forgot to set the NSURLConnection delegate

Comment: While this works, but sometimes it just fails. It's pretty weird. All those delegate method is called just like when it works, but I got "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “mysite.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." I used NSURLConnection `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it, Looks like NSURLConnection `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` doesn't work well when we skip certificate check (in `-connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` NSURLConnection delegate method). I suspect that it's the use of NSOperationQueue that breaks the flow. Solution: I change it to setup NSURLConnection with BlocksKit and call `-start` manually, now it works perfectly.

Comment: This answer only works for async requests.  If using `sendSynchronousRequest:` instead, you'll want to see the top-voted answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766755/ignoring-certificate-errors-with-nsurlconnection

Comment: Works perfect for NSURLConnection. Any advice for NSURLSession?

Comment: Is it indended that in case both conditions are satsified you're doing both `useCredential` and `continueWithoutCredential…`?

Comment: I'm confused now by this answer.  We are getting this error `<Error>: Connection 818: TLS Trust encountered error 3:-9807` occurring on devices and changing `allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost` now throws `Failed to fetch URL configuration, error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202`.  The answer doesn't fix the issue it.  It seems like things have changed since its initial posting, but trying to use the updates in the comments is creating build errors.  Can anyone post a full answer using the updates in the comments?

Answer (score 36):

If you're unwilling (or unable) to use private APIs, there's an open source (BSD license) library called [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) that provides a wrapper around the lower-level `CFNetwork APIs`. They recently introduced the ability to allow `HTTPS connections` using self-signed or untrusted certificates with the `-setValidatesSecureCertificate:` API. If you don't want to pull in the whole library, you could use the source as a reference for implementing the same functionality yourself.

Comment: Tim, you may find yourself wanting to use async for other reasons anyway (like being able to show a progress bar), I find for all but the most simple of requests that's the way I go.  So maybe you should just implement Async now and save the hassle later.

Comment: See this for the implementation (but use [r setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]; ): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657786/asihttprequest-ignores-setvalidatessecurecertificate-parameter

Comment: Sorry that I brought this topic back up. But since the iOS 5 introduced the ARC features. How can I make this work now?

Comment: Could you please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56627757/1364053

Answer (score 33):

Ideally, there should only be two scenarios of when an iOS application would need to accept an un-trusted certificate.

Scenario A: You are connected to a test environment which is using a self-signed certificate.

Scenario B: You are Proxying `HTTPS` traffic using a `MITM Proxy like Burp Suite, Fiddler, OWASP ZAP, etc.` The Proxies will return a certificate signed by a self-signed CA so that the proxy is able to capture `HTTPS` traffic.

Production hosts should never use un-trusted certificates for [obvious reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

If you need to have the iOS simulator accept an un-trusted certificate for testing purposes it is highly recommended that you do not change application logic in order disable the built in certificate validation provided by the `NSURLConnection` APIs. If the application is released to the public without removing this logic, it will be susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks.

The recommended way to accept un-trusted certificates for testing purposes is to import the Certificate Authority(CA) certificate which signed the certificate onto your iOS Simulator or iOS device. I wrote up a quick blog post which demonstrates how to do this which an iOS Simulator at:

[accepting untrusted certificates using the ios simulator](http://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2011/8/7/accepting-un-trusted-certificates-using-the-ios-simulator.html)

Comment: Awesome stuff man. I agree, it's so easy to forget about disabling this special app logic to accept any untrusted certificate.

Comment: "Ideally, there should only be two scenarios of when an iOS application would need to accept an un-trusted certificate." - How about rejecting a 'claimed' good certifcate when pinning a certifcate? Confer: Dignotar (pwn'd) and Trustwave (MitM fame).

Comment: Totally agree with your statement about forgetting to remove the code. The irony is that it's much easier to make this change in the code than getting the simulator to accept self-signed certs.

Answer (score 12):

`NSURLRequest` has a private method called `setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:forHost:`, which will do exactly what you'd like. You could define the `allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:` method on `NSURLRequest` via a category, and set it to return `YES` for the host that you'd like to override.

Comment: Usual caveats about undocumented APIs apply... but good to know that it's possible.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I've added another answer which doesn't involve the use of private APIs.

Comment: Does that work when you use "NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:"?

Answer (score 12):

To complement the accepted answer, for much better security, you could add your server certificate or your own root CA certificate to keychain( https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941559/1432048), however doing this alone won't make NSURLConnection authenticate your self-signed server automatically.  You still need to add the below code to your NSURLConnection delegate, it's copied from Apple sample code [AdvancedURLConnections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html), and you need to add two files(Credentials.h, Credentials.m) from apple sample code to your projects.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
//        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])

    OSStatus                err;
    NSURLProtectionSpace *  protectionSpace;
    SecTrustRef             trust;
    SecTrustResultType      trustResult;
    BOOL                    trusted;

    protectionSpace = [challenge protectionSpace];
    assert(protectionSpace != nil);

    trust = [protectionSpace serverTrust];
    assert(trust != NULL);
    err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
    trusted = (err == noErr) && ((trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed) || (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified));

    // If that fails, apply our certificates as anchors and see if that helps.
    //
    // It's perfectly acceptable to apply all of our certificates to the SecTrust
    // object, and let the SecTrust object sort out the mess.  Of course, this assumes
    // that the user trusts all certificates equally in all situations, which is implicit
    // in our user interface; you could provide a more sophisticated user interface
    // to allow the user to trust certain certificates for certain sites and so on).

    if ( ! trusted ) {
        err = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, (CFArrayRef) [Credentials sharedCredentials].certificates);
        if (err == noErr) {
            err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
        }
        trusted = (err == noErr) && ((trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed) || (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified));
    }
    if(trusted)
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I can't take any credit for this, [but this one I found](http://chariotsolutions.blogspot.com/2009/09/iphone-and-ssl.html) worked really well for my needs. `shouldAllowSelfSignedCert` is my `BOOL` variable. Just add to your `NSURLConnection` delegate and you should be rockin for a quick bypass on a per connection basis.

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)space {
     if([[space authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
          if(shouldAllowSelfSignedCert) {
               return YES; // Self-signed cert will be accepted
          } else {
               return NO;  // Self-signed cert will be rejected
          }
          // Note: it doesn't seem to matter what you return for a proper SSL cert
          //       only self-signed certs
     }
     // If no other authentication is required, return NO for everything else
     // Otherwise maybe YES for NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault and etc.
     return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In iOS 9, SSL connections will fail for all invalid or self-signed certificates. This is the default behavior of the new [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) feature in iOS 9.0 or later, and on OS X 10.11 and later.

You can override this behavior in the `Info.plist`, by setting `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES` in the `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary. *However, I recommend overriding this setting for testing purposes only.*

[image]

For information see App Transport Technote [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote).

Comment: The only solution worked for me, I have no way to change the Firebase framework to suite my needs, that solved it, thanks!

Comment: Now I saw that Google ask for NSAllowArbitraryLoads = YES for Admob (in Firebase). https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/ios9

Answer (score 7):

The category workaround posted by Nathan de Vries will pass the AppStore private API checks, and is useful in cases where you do not have control of the `NSUrlConnection` object.
One example is `NSXMLParser` which will open the URL you supply, but does not expose the `NSURLRequest` or `NSURLConnection`.

In iOS 4 the workaround still seems to work, but only on the device, the Simulator does not invoke the `allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:` method anymore.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `NSURLConnectionDelegate` to allow HTTPS connections and there are new callbacks with iOS8.

**Deprecated:**

```
connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:
connection:didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:
connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
```

Instead those, you need to declare:

> `connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:` - Sent to determine whether the URL loader should use the credential storage for authenticating the connection.
>
> `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` - Tells the delegate that the connection will send a request for an authentication challenge.

With `willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge` you can use `challenge` like you did with the deprecated methods, for example:

```
// Trusting and not trusting connection to host: Self-signed certificate
[challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

Comment: Could you please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56627757/1364053

Answer (score 3):

I posted some gist code (based on someone else's work which I note) that lets you properly authenticate against a self generated certificate (and how to get a free certificate - see comments bottom of [Cocoanetics](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/12/nsurlconnection-with-self-signed-certificates/))

My code is here [github](https://gist.github.com/2051599)

Comment: Could you please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56627757/1364053

Answer (score 3):

You can use this Code

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
     if ([[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust)
     {
         [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:[[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust]] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
     }
}
```

Use `-connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` instead of these Deprecated Methods

**Deprecated:**

```
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace  
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep using **sendSynchronousRequest** i work in this solution:

```
FailCertificateDelegate *fcd=[[FailCertificateDelegate alloc] init];

NSURLConnection *c=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:fcd startImmediately:NO];
[c setDelegateQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]];
[c start];    
NSData *d=[fcd getData];
```

you can see it here: [Objective-C SSL Synchronous Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18843828/1662307)

Answer (score 1):

With [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) I have successfully consumed https webservice with below code,

```
NSString *aStrServerUrl = WS_URL;

// Initialize AFHTTPRequestOperationManager...
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES; 
[manager POST:aStrServerUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    successBlock(operation, responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    errorBlock(operation, error);
}];
```