# HTTPS with self-signed certificate in the app's keychain

Tags: iphone, keychain, self-signed

I have to connect my iPhone app to a server with a self-signed certificate via HTTPS. I cannot change the certificate or the server.

Since I don't want to accept all self-signed certs, just this one, my idea was to import the cert to the apps keychain (reading the cert from file and adding it to the keychain with `SecItemAdd`).

If I run the App in the Simulator, install the cert and then search the keychain for it (using `SecItemCopyMatching`), the cert is found, but the connection still fails with *"untrusted server certificate"* error.

Is this a problem with the simulator or my app? Do I have to do anything else, for this to work? Or can I assume, that if I add a certificate to the keychain on a real device, the connect to the server will be successfull(I'm using `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest`)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library. It allows to ignore certificate validation by setting `validatesSecureCertificate` property of `ASIHTTPRequest` object to `NO`.

Comment: Wouldn't this change my app to accept any self-signed certificate? I would like to enable connections only with this specific cert. Is this possible with a keychain entry at all (like in Java)?

Comment: this property is just set to the request, not for the whole app.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I actually meant requests, not the whole app. I would like to establish the connection only if the server has that specific cert, not any other self-signed. Is it possible with the keychain entry?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in the Simulator with some caveats, see the Apple sample code example "AdvancedURLConnections".

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the Apple sample code. It really helps me a lot. For a very simplified version, please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21621522/1432048)  to another similar question.