# iOS how to use SecCertificateCreateWithData

Tags: ios, iphone, security, ssl, x509certificate

I am working on a HTTPSClient for iOS. I have a CA Certificate in DER format in my application in order to perform Trust & Evaluation. Unfortunately I am not able to load the certificate with `SecCertificateCreateWithData`. My caRef stays nil and I do not get an error message.

(I export my CA certificate from a windows server)

certDataRef always has some bytes.

I also stumbled across
[Created a certificate using SecCertificateCreateWithData on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700575/created-a-certificate-using-seccertificatecreatewithdata-on-ios) and
[iPhone Simulator custom CA certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329163/iphone-simulator-custom-ca-certificate?rq=1) . Is it true that iOS requires some certificate attributes/extensions? Or do I just have to run this on a device instead of the simulator?

```
NSData *derCA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:caDerFilePath];
if (!derCA) {
    return nil;
}
        
CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)derCA;
SecCertificateRef caRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFDataRef)(derCA));
if (!caRef) {
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have DER formatted cert you can do the following two steps and SecCertificateCreateWithData will work.

1. Make DER to PEM. Use command: `openssl x509 -in urcert.der -inform DER -out urcert.pem -outform PEM`.
2. In the PEM formatted cert you will have `---BEGING CERT ----` and `---- END CERT ---` which you have to strip off. You can use command like this to get rid of the first and last line: `tail -n +2 urcert.pem | head -n -1 > urcert.pem.new && mv urcert.pem.new urcert.pem`

Now you can execute the code you had to load the cert and feed to SecCertificateCreateWithData.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and in my case the certificate file data was in base64 format. While this worked perfectly on android and windows, I had to decode base 64 string into byte array and save the file in binary format for making it work with iOS.