# How do I ignore an "invalid" SSL certificate in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Currently I have:

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"auth.login",@"username",@"password", nil];
NSData* packed_array = [array messagePack];

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://192.168.1.149:3790/api/1.0"];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Previously the below had changed by hostname.
//[request setValue:@"RPC Server" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];

[request setValue:@"binary/message-pack" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[packed_array length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:packed_array];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
responseData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]];

NSLog(@"response data: %@",[responseData messagePackParse]);
NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
NSLog(@"called canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace");
return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];  
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
NSLog(@"called didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");
[challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];  
}
```

Which returns `"Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid"…`"

How should I be implementing the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert) **and** getting data back?

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert

Comment: Did you neglect to read the question? :^\ I was unable to implement the code in that answer.

Comment: You haven't posted the code that instantiates the NSURLConnection. Are you properly setting it's delegate to an object that implements those two methods?

Comment: I used `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]` to receive the data. I never instantiated a NSURLConnection object. How would I go about doing so and setting the delegate to self? I tried creating a NSURLConnection object before but I couldn't figure out how to set the delegate. While on the other hand I couldn't figure out how to get an asynchronous connection (which is recommended correct?) instead of the synchronous method I've used to spit out NSData.

Comment: How do I set the delegate for NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem(s). First I fixed the way [I was using the delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126595/nsurlconnection-delegate-methods-not-being-called) and secondly I changed the host. I edited the code to remove the changing of the host and commented it. *I still don't think my question was a duplicate…*

Answer (score 0):

If your application flow needs the syncronous request, i answer something similar here [Objective-C SSL Synchronous Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18843828/1662307)