# NSURLConnection, NSURLRequest, untrusted cert and user authentication

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, nsurlcredential

Morning Everyone,

I've been attempting to write an application that does some GETs from a remote Web Service that requires authentication. My main problem is that the majority of these remote servers (and there are a lot of them) don't have valid certificates. I've got [code to accept the invalid certificate](http://tinyurl.com/37rgupc) and code to respond to the challenge with the correct uname & pass (below). The problem I'm having is getting the two to play together. I can't seem to find a way to send the challenge both `NSURLCredential`s or a way to chain the callbacks correctly. When I try to chain them I can't get my `NSURLRequest` to call `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` twice.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Code for Authentication...

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{   
    if(!hasCanceled){
        if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
            NSURLCredential *newCredential;
            newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:_username password:_password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } 
        else {
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            NSLog(@"Bad Username Or Password");
            badUsernameAndPassword = YES;
            finished = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only reply to an `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` with a credential for that challenge. You can determine what type of challenge you've received using:

```
[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod]
```

The possible values are [documented here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLProtectionSpace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001828-DontLinkElementID_4). In the case of an invalid server certificate, the authentication method will be `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust`. In your code, you should check the authentication method and respond appropriately.

```
if ([challenge previousFailureCount] > 0) {
    // handle bad credentials here
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    return;
}

if ([[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
    // check if the user has previously accepted the certificate, otherwise prompt
} else if ([[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == /* your supported authentication method here */) {
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:/* your user's credential */ forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

It's not an error if you don't get both authentication challenges each time. You can cache credentials when you create them. If you do, you won't necessarily be prompted again.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Needed to implement the "canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace" method correctly to get my app to call this method. But after that all is well. Thanks!