# "untrusted server certificate" on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, status

I am writing an iPhone application and I would like to connect to a 'HTTPS' server to get some information. However, I get the error in the console which is

> NSUnderlyingError = Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202
>   UserInfo=0x3e95cf0 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You
>   might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “example.com”
>   which could put your confidential information at risk."; }

How can I trust the certificate and get the http status code 200

The following is my code.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request_get2 = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request_get2 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com"]]; 
    [request_get2 setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request_get2 setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //[request_get2 setValue:@"text/html; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request_get2 setValue:@"https://www.example.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer"];
    [request_get2 setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
    // cookiesString is in format "cookieName=cookieValue;"
    [request_get2 setValue: (NSString *) cookiesString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];


    // doGet - response
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response_get2 = nil;  // it change from 'NSURLRespaonse' to 'NSHTTPURLResponse'
    NSError *error_get2 = nil;
    NSData *responseData_get2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request_get2 returningResponse:&response_get2 error:&error_get2];
    NSString *data_get2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData_get2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (!error_get2) {
        NSString *responseURL_get2 = [[response_get2 URL] absoluteString];           // null value
        NSString *responseTextEncodingName_get2 = [response_get2 textEncodingName];  // null value
        NSString *responseMIMEType_get2 = [response_get2 MIMEType];                  // null value
        NSUInteger *responseStatusCode_get2 = [response_get2 statusCode]; //[responseStatusCode intValue]; // the status code is 0
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"\nsomething went wrong: %@\n", [error_get2 userInfo]); // got the error in here
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that adding an untrusted certificate is (at least in the simulator) not possible, but you can tell your NSURLConnection Delegate to accept self signed certificates (or generally untrusted ones)

The following link helped me solve the issue!

[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Comment: thank you, sam. It is very useful. But I still have 1 questions, where should I put the code. I used to put the code within a .m class. But it did not work. I checked the apple developer website, I know those are pre-defined functions, but where should I call it? I also used to put the NSLog() to print the content, but I could not see the content of the NSLog. thank you very much.

Comment: please see my answer in your other thread with the same question :).. thxs

Answer (score 0):

Trusting all certificates is a very bad idea. A malicious person can perform a *Man-in-the-Middle* attack on your users to read or change all transferred data.

I believe your certificate doesn't contain all intermediate certificates necessary to validate path to a system trusted root certificate. It can be reported as *incomplete certificate chain* by some SSL config validation tools.

You can solve the *incomplete certificate chain* issue manually by concatenating all certificates from the certificate to the trusted root certificate (exclusive, in this order), to prevent such issues. Note, the trusted root certificate should not be there, as it is already included in the system’s root certificate store.

You should be able to fetch intermediate certificates from the issuer and concat them together by yourself. I have written a script to automate the procedure, it takes a certificate to produce output of correctly chained certificates. https://github.com/zakjan/cert-chain-resolver