# XMPPFramework - Security Options

Tags: ios, security, xmpp, xmppframework

I want to implement server side security using XMPPFramework.Server has to validate certificates from client before establishing connection. I found out that there are these methods which could do this:

```
kCFStreamSSLLevel
kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates
kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots
kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot
kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain
kCFStreamSSLPeerName
kCFStreamSSLCertificates
```

But I don't know what are used for what. Can anyone help me what and how to use these methods for server side security? Server is Openfire and client is iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the following 5 security options you listed has been deprecated.

```
kCFStreamSSLLevel
kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates
kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots
kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot
kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain
```

From [XMPPFramework - GCDAsyncSocket:](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Vendor/CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h)

```
* ==== The following UNAVAILABLE KEYS are: (with throw an exception)
 * 
 * - kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot (UNAVAILABLE)
 *     You MUST use manual trust evaluation instead (see GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust).
 *     Corresponding deprecated method: SSLSetAllowsAnyRoot
 * 
 * - kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredRoots (UNAVAILABLE)
 *     You MUST use manual trust evaluation instead (see GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust).
 *     Corresponding deprecated method: SSLSetAllowsExpiredRoots
 *
 * - kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates (UNAVAILABLE)
 *     You MUST use manual trust evaluation instead (see GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust).
 *     Corresponding deprecated method: SSLSetAllowsExpiredCerts
 *
 * - kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain (UNAVAILABLE)
 *     You MUST use manual trust evaluation instead (see GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust).
 *     Corresponding deprecated method: SSLSetEnableCertVerify
 *
 * - kCFStreamSSLLevel (UNAVAILABLE)
 *     You MUST use GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMin & GCDAsyncSocketSSLProtocolVersionMin instead.
 *     Corresponding deprecated method: SSLSetProtocolVersionEnabled
 *
 * 
 * Please refer to Apple's documentation for corresponding SSLFunctions.
```

As for the other 2 options,

From [Apple Documentation - Secure Transport Reference:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/secureTransportRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SSLSetPeerDomainName)

Call `SSLSetPeerDomainName` to specify the fully-qualified domain name of the peer to which you want to connect (optional but highly recommended).

Call `SSLSetCertificate` to specify the certificate to be used in authentication (required for server side, optional for client).

---

Your best bet would be to:

**Use**

`GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust` in `xmppStream:willSecureWithSettings:`

**Then**

Validate your server's certificate in `xmppStream:didReceiveTrust:`.

Comment: @vishnuvarthan Check out the codes in question and answer of this post: [iOS and SSL: Unable to validate self-signed server certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979922/ios-and-ssl-unable-to-validate-self-signed-server-certificate)

Comment: The link uses NSURL but i don't want NSURL i am implementing XMPP.Can you tell me the methods similar to the link which i gave in the previous comment.I am looking for something like that.

Comment: @KeithOYS hey have you ever implemented file transfer functionality? if yes then can you please help to solve some issue regarding file transfer.

Comment: @KeithOYS I have a certificate in my app bundle given by server,  how do i import the certificate in my code and send it to server for authentication.

Comment: @KeithOYS Can you tell how to use TLS version 1.0 in xmpp

Answer (score 1):

Just have the diagnostics ignore it until a replacement method can be developed. Use this above the effected code.
`#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"`