# Ignoring SSL certificate errors with NSURLConnection

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, sendasynchronousrequest

I'm using `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)]` to pull data from a web service, but the web server has a self-issued certificate, causing this error to appear:

[image: SSL Error]

Error displayed using:

```
NSAlert *a = [NSAlert alertWithError:error];
[a runModal];
```

Is there any way to ignore this error and continue anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignoring certificate errors with NSURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766755/ignoring-certificate-errors-with-nsurlconnection)

Comment: I figured this had been asked before and located and retitled the earlier question. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Comment: You're right it is a dupe (although I didn't get that answer because I searched for `sendAsynchronousRequest`, so this question is for that method specifically).

Comment: *"Ignoring SSL certificate errors with NSURLConnection"* - its better to fix the problem rather than ignoring the error (assuming its a non-trivial error, like a fake certificate rather than an expired certificate). If you are not going to use PKI and SSL correctly, then why use it at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the instructions in the linked question, I defined a dummy interface for NSURLConnection:

```
@interface NSURLRequest (DummyInterface)
+ (void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)allow forHost:(NSString*)host;
@end
```

And called the method before creating the request:

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

This suppressed the error about the certificate being invalid.

Comment: Isn't this private API?

Comment: Yes it is, but my app is not in the app store, but distributed directly, so I do not need to worry about rejection. Of course, I run the risk of the API changing in later versions of OS X, as this is undocumented.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to make sure

Comment: *"I run the risk of the API changing..."* - how about the risk of leaking and losing information for anyone who attacks? Do you tell your customers about it?

Answer (score 0):

This may be rejected by Apple. Use the proper implementation of NSConnectiondatadelegate:

see a way around it:
[Stackoverflow response to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Comment: I cannot use an `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method, as I am calling `-sendAsynchronousRequest`. Nonetheless, this is a moot point now for my app as I solved the problem by purchasing an SSL cert for the server.