# ios swift POST error NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https

I am getting an error when sending https post request  to a https server on ios9

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

my info.pst has

> ```
>   <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>       <dict>          <key>myserver.com</key>
>       <dict>
>           <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
>           <false/>
>           <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
>           <string>TLSv1.0</string>
>           <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
>           <true/>
>           <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
>           <true/>             </dict>         </dict>
> ```

I tried to disable ATS by using

> ```
>   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
>     <dict>
>         <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
>         <true/>
>               </dict>
> ```

but i was getting a different error
HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Myserver.com uses TLS 1.0.
The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with HMAC-SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

UPDATE: Adding ssl report from ssllabs.com

> Authentication
>
> Server Key and Certificate #1 Subject Dummy Certificate  Fingerprint
>   SHA1: 3449de1a15e1ecc81f934aed4587d93b56befd94 Pin SHA256:
>   SLJAAtLuQ5nALXXAWlM30bBFQfurZ+QnxdZK5g4O11E= Common names Dummy
>   Certificate   MISMATCH Alternative names  - Valid from    Wed, 14 Jan 2009
>   21:36:55 UTC Valid until  Tue, 09 Jan 2029 21:36:55 UTC (expires in 12
>   years and 9 months) Key   RSA 1024 bits (Exponent 65537)   WEAK Weak key
>   (Debian)  No Issuer   Dummy Certificate   Self-signed  Signature
>   algorithm MD5withRSA   INSECURE Extended Validation   No Certificate
>   Transparency  No Revocation information   None  Trusted   No   NOT TRUSTED
>   (Why?)
>
> Additional Certificates (if supplied) Certificates provided   1 (491
>   bytes) Chain issues   None
>
> Certification Paths Path #1: Not trusted (path does not chain to a
>   trusted anchor) 1 Sent by server    Not in trust store    Dummy
>   Certificate   Self-signed  Fingerprint SHA1:
>   3449de1a15e1ecc81f934aed4587d93b56befd94 Pin SHA256:
>   SLJAAtLuQ5nALXXAWlM30bBFQfurZ+QnxdZK5g4O11E=  RSA 1024 bits (e 65537)
>   / MD5withRSA  WEAK KEY  Weak or insecure signature, but no impact on
>   root certificate Configuration
>
> Protocols TLS 1.2 No TLS 1.1  No TLS 1.0  Yes SSL 3   No SSL 2    No
>
> Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order; deprecated and
>   SSL 2 suites at the end) TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)  256
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   128 TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)
>   INSECURE  128 TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)   INSECURE   128
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)   112
>
> Handshake Simulation Android 2.3.7   No SNI 2 RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  No FS Android 4.0.4   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Android 4.1.1   RSA 1024
>   (MD5)     TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Android 4.2.2   RSA
>   1024 (MD5)    TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Android
>   4.3   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Android 4.4.2   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
>   No FS Android 5.0.0   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Baidu Jan 2015  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS BingPreview Jan 2015    RSA
>   1024 (MD5)    TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Chrome 48 /
>   OS X  R   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS
>   Firefox 31.3.0 ESR / Win 7    RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Firefox 42 / OS X  R    RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Firefox 44 / OS X 
>   R RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS
>   Googlebot Feb 2015    RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS IE 6 / XP   No FS 1   No SNI 2  Server closed connection IE 7 / Vista   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS IE 8 / XP   No FS 1   No SNI 2  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA  RC4 IE 8-10 / Win
>   7  R  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS IE
>   11 / Win 7  R RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
>   No FS IE 11 / Win 8.1  R  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS IE 10 / Win Phone 8.0   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS IE 11 / Win Phone
>   8.1  R    RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS IE 11 / Win Phone 8.1 Update  R RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS IE 11 / Win 10  R   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Edge 13 / Win 10 
>   R RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Edge 13
>   / Win Phone 10  R RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Java 6u45   No SNI 2    RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  No FS Java 7u25   RSA 1024
>   (MD5)     TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  No FS Java 8u31   RSA 1024
>   (MD5)     TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA  No FS OpenSSL 0.9.8y  RSA
>   1024 (MD5)    TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS OpenSSL
>   1.0.1l  R RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS OpenSSL 1.0.2e  R   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Safari 5.1.9 / OS X 10.6.8  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Safari 6 /
>   iOS 6.0.1  R  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No
>   FS Safari 6.0.4 / OS X 10.8.4  R  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Safari 7 / iOS 7.1  R   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Safari 7 / OS X
>   10.9  R   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Safari 8 / iOS 8.4  R   RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Safari 8 / OS X 10.10  R    RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Safari 9 /
>   iOS 9  R  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS
>   Safari 9 / OS X 10.11  R  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS
>   1.0   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9  R  Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure Yahoo Slurp Jan 2015 RSA 1024
>   (MD5)     TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS YandexBot Jan
>   2015  RSA 1024 (MD5)      TLS 1.0 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  No FS (1)
>   Clients that do not support Forward Secrecy (FS) are excluded when
>   determining support for it. (2) No support for virtual SSL hosting
>   (SNI). Connects to the default site if the server uses SNI. (3) Only
>   first connection attempt simulated. Browsers sometimes retry with a
>   lower protocol version. (R) Denotes a reference browser or client,
>   with which we expect better effective security. (All) We use defaults,
>   but some platforms do not use their best protocols and features (e.g.,
>   Java 6 & 7, older IE).
>
> Protocol Details DROWN (experimental)  IP
>   Address   Port    Export  Special Status
>   54.64.244.95  443 Yes Yes Vulnerable (same key with SSL v2)
>   217.89.70.156 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   195.167.179.101   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   209.166.166.21    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   46.105.254.39 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   212.35.116.41 443 Yes No  Not checked
>   54.83.3.22    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   120.76.43.8   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.30.94.252  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   116.213.215.22    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   202.217.48.250    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.74.112.186 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   134.65.5.183  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   146.82.88.157 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   79.99.32.99   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   185.59.164.24 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   195.246.16.19 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   193.95.228.59 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.49.49.147  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   209.166.166.58    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   206.18.241.170    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   68.71.100.110 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.83.4.144   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   144.34.10.154 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   121.41.22.133 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   89.236.107.116    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   116.213.215.21    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   211.94.93.245 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.31.237.200 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   31.14.137.165 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   209.61.135.205    443 No  Yes Not checked
>   54.65.106.240 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   203.182.36.10 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   194.126.208.94    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   199.43.209.147    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   216.32.194.132    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.74.168.71  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   49.231.16.61  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   101.231.206.152   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   166.78.43.90  443 No  Yes Not checked
>   144.34.10.153 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   184.173.17.183    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.83.4.148   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   193.15.201.74 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   198.11.237.88 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.83.4.142   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   167.219.19.1  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.18.134.67  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   202.217.48.210    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   219.239.94.78 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   144.34.10.152 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   120.25.144.137    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   206.18.241.171    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.255.177.46 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   61.8.234.239  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   195.246.16.20 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   5.153.50.91   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   116.213.215.12    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   118.145.20.104    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   199.106.146.196   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   194.6.195.138 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   219.239.94.75 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   134.65.7.97   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.83.4.141   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   23.246.192.246    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   193.15.201.71 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   195.198.142.218   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   209.61.135.204    443 No  Yes Not checked
>   144.34.10.151 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.172.242.114    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   116.213.215.16    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   116.213.215.39    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   139.219.133.76    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   72.3.166.215  443 No  Yes Not checked
>   75.89.220.209 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   217.89.135.187    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.209.9.96   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.83.3.12    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   140.239.26.70 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   116.213.215.19    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   213.221.87.106    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.48.52.65   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   61.160.121.200    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   52.18.87.225  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.77.148.144 443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   184.173.86.115    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   5.153.57.96   443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   206.18.241.130    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   203.126.84.111    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   116.213.215.17    443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   54.209.27.62  443 Yes Yes Not checked
>   206.18.241.131    443 Yes Yes Not checked (1) For a better understanding of this test, please read this longer explanation (2) Key usage data
>   kindly provided by the Censys network search engine; original DROWN
>   test here (3) Censys data is only indicative of possible key and
>   certificate reuse; possibly out-of-date and incomplete (4) We perform
>   real-time key reuse checks, but stop checking after first confirmed
>   vulnerability (5) The "Special" column indicates vulnerable OpenSSL
>   version; "Export" refers to export cipher suites Secure
>   Renegotiation Supported Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation No
>   Insecure Client-Initiated Renegotiation   No BEAST attack Not mitigated
>   server-side (more info)   TLS 1.0: 0x35 POODLE (SSLv3)    No, SSL 3 not
>   supported (more info) POODLE (TLS)    No (more info) Downgrade attack
>   prevention    Unknown (requires support for at least two protocols, excl.
>   SSL2) SSL/TLS compression No RC4  Yes   INSECURE (more info) Heartbeat
>   (extension)   No Heartbleed (vulnerability)   No (more info) OpenSSL CCS
>   vuln. (CVE-2014-0224) No (more info) Forward Secrecy  No   WEAK (more
>   info) ALPN    No NPN  No Session resumption (caching) Yes Session
>   resumption (tickets)  No OCSP stapling    No Strict Transport Security
>   (HSTS)    No HSTS Preloading  Not in: Chrome  Edge  Firefox  IE  Tor 
>   Public Key Pinning (HPKP) No Public Key Pinning Report-Only   No Long
>   handshake intolerance No TLS extension intolerance    No TLS version
>   intolerance   TLS 1.98    TLS 2.98  Incorrect SNI alerts  No Uses common DH
>   primes    No, DHE suites not supported DH public server param (Ys)
>   reuse No, DHE suites not supported SSL 2 handshake compatibility  Yes
>
> Miscellaneous Test date   Mon, 28 Mar 2016 15:16:39 UTC Test
>   duration  37.404 seconds HTTP status code 302 HTTP
>   forwarding    http://myserver.com   PLAINTEXT HTTP server signature   -
>   Server hostname   IP-216-37-62-164.nframe.net

Xcode 7.3
OSX 10.11.13
Apple Swift version 2.2

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: can you test your server configuration with http://ssllabs.com ?

Comment: Actually  i used third party API domain  @Tom,   How do i overcome this ?

Comment: you can test the domain of that third party

Comment: @Tom, i have run the ssl report on ssllabs. it is using Dummy Certificate, TLS 1.0. There are lot of details. How do i make sense of these to fix my error. Do i post that report here ?

Comment: if you can post it, it's better

Comment: @Tom, Thanks ..I posted the report

Comment: @Tom, is there a workaround.? when app goes to production, we will have valid ssl.

Comment: Probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766755/ignoring-certificate-errors-with-nsurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

According to the ssllabs report :

1. The certificate is NOT trusted
2. Even if it was trusted, the certificate is NOT valid for that domain
3. The server answer a redirect (probably to the http version)

Comment: Just for the development & testing, can i disable this restriction and make Https post rest calls to this domain. i also checked http calls, they are not working.  production domain should have valid ssl.Its only for dev machine.