# How to access self signed SSL certificate(insecure https requests) on Cordova for iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ssl-certificate, cordova-plugins

While making http request, app is working fine but when the https url is hit, following error occur -

`NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed(kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)`

Already tried solutions -

1. [Ignoring certificate errors with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766755/ignoring-certificate-errors-with-nsurlconnection)
2. [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823)

but no success.
Could someone provide a working solution?