# How to use ssl certificate & HTTPS implementation in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ssl, https

HI

Can any one guide me how to use the ssl certificate and how to implement the HTTPS call .to make my application more secure.There is any way to implement the process.pls get the sample or links 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but there's some useful information on using SSL in Obj-C here: [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Comment: Can u get me the details of the Trusted and untrusted certificate.im new in this development.