# Authentication method calling problem on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

When I have established SSL connection with NSURLConnection, I need to change certificates in credentials to make new request. But when I make new request, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace method don't fires and request use credentials which were setted to previous request. I've already tried to add '#' to the end of the URL, clear cookies,  but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you impelemented the NSURLConnection delegate protocol,because that can be the only known cause why the       canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace method is not fired.

Take a look at

```
@protocol NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender <NSObject>
```

in the Apple documentation

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert) thread.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that those methods from protocol fires only once for the first request and for next requests not.