# NSURL Connection

Tags: iphone, ssl, nsurl

I found this link 
[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823)

But being new to iPhone dev, I couldn't figure out where to put this code and make it run. What I want is, I've a certificate and with every request to server I need to present the certificate, as every request is unique. So will the above solution work for me too or how should I do it ???
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using ASIHttpRequest...

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions