# How to connect with https url?

Tags: iphone, security, ios4, https, ssl-certificate

I'm making an application in which my application needs to connect to an https server in secure way. how do i do that? Please explain me ...

Comment: You will get a much better response if you take some time to put some more detail in your question.  What type of connection are you after?  What have you tried already?  Can you connect in an "insecure" way?

Comment: i want to connect my applicaton to an https server. not in insecure way. i dont want to try wats in the following ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert

Answer (score 2):

I will make certain assumptions in answering this question. I assume that you are using NSURLRequest and it is working for HTTP URLs. It is failing for HTTPS URL.

The most common reason that have seen for HTTPS request to fail is due to certificate trust issues e.g. use of self signed certificates. I assume that you are bumping into this. Have a look at:

[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Comment: no i dont want to use these method any other idea?? becoz i have not much knowledge.