# How to open self signed crt file in objective c so it will open in settings?

Tags: objective-c, x509certificate

*The following question is for an app that is just for personal use and will NOT be sended for review to Apple*

I have an self-signed certificate for personal use which I will use to connect to an server. 
When you click an .crt file within the standard mail app in iOS it will open in the settings app. After that it will asks you if you want to add this "profile" to the device and use it in the future.
I would like to have that same behavior within my app. 
So normally if I wanted to open an file in another app I would use *UIDocumentInteractionController*. If I try that with the .crt file it will simple tell me that there are no apps  to open that file. 
There are indeed no apps that will open the app, but iOS is not suggesting that maybe it could be opened with the settings app.

Question: Is there anyway I can open a .crt file from within my app so it will open in the settings app and it would be possible to add it to .crt profiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Install SSL certificate programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798950/ios-install-ssl-certificate-programatically)

Comment: Ok so tried that, but it won't work. Is "kSecTrustSettingsResult" some sort of class constant? It is giving me an error. I included the security class.