# ios self signed certificates

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to create a self signed certificate from your own ios application?

Answer (score 4):

Is this more what you're after?
[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Answer (score 1):

**Certificate configuration:**

You have to install the *Self Signed Certificate* or *CA* on the device in order for the device to trust it
then only device trusts the SSL connection.

In the case of installing *self signed certificate* make sure *domain name* of the *URL* is same as *Common name* of certificate.

If there is no domain name then IP address is fine.

**Certificate installation:**

You can just host it on the web server and try to access it from safari then iOS will prompt for the certificate installation in the iOS Device

**Certificate Creation:**

Here is the way to create self signed certificate so that you can fill all the details and host in web server.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 1001 -nodes
```

(Pay attention while entering the value for Common Name)