# how to post secure data via iPhone?

Tags: iphone

For example, I want to sent information like credit card number, password etc so what's the best way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send with SSL encryption. Have a look at [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert) for some code

Answer (score 0):

use encryption
 algorithms......

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting to a web service, make sure you are using a HTTPS connection when you are calling to:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequest returningResponse: nil error: &error ];
```