# ssl connection in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My question is, i would like to use an ssl connection in my IOS Application. there is aself-signed ssl in the server. is there anything to do in my iPhone app ( any configuration ) or just i will access my url with https instead of http. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did you already *try* to use `https://`?

Comment: When i test my web services ( wsdl) with soapui, it show an error : bad request. what's this mean please ? the problem is in my Web services or in my app ?? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the https address, NSURLRequest and others are smart enough to take care of the encryption.

Comment: When i test my web services ( wsdl) with soapui, it shows an error : bad request. what's this mean please ? the problem is in my Web services or in my app ?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASIHTTPRequest you can set this:

```
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
```

Otherwise, look at this answer for NSURLConnection:

[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Comment: its the same thing. When i test my web services ( wsdl) with soapui, it show an error : bad request. what's this mean please ? the problem is in my Web services or in my app ?? thanks

Comment: Need more information - getting a 500 error? Are the NSURLConnection delegates being called (assuming that's what you are using?)

Comment: Ok this is my problem. I am using ASIHTTPRequest and soap/wsdl web services.i have already used it with an other url ( development url) and it is forked fine, but now my client give me an other url ( wsdl, production url) but when i test it, it give me the error 400, bad request. i haver test it with soapui and it's the same thing