# ssl and certificate questions for api access only

Tags: iphone, ios, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a mobile app that will be communicating with my webserver over https.  My question is, do I even need to worry about installing a certificate since all traffic to this api will be headless?

In my understanding, SSL provides the encryption for a request, and a certificate establishes trust for the end user.  Because these calls to my webserver will essentially be headless, I'm thinking I don't need to worry about the trust establishment.

Am I correct in this thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will either need a **[self-signed certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate)** or a **[CA-signed certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority)** in order to use [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure#Technical) on your server.

If your certificate is not assigned to you by a certificate authority, then any connection you make will [trigger an error in your `URLRequest` that you will have to handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert). The problem with an untrusted certificate is that [a malicious man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) could fake data to and from your server with his own self-signed certificate, and possibly pick up authentication credentials or data that he should not have access to.

If you are dealing with any authentication credentials or other private data, I'd recommend just requesting a signed certificate. If you shop around, you can find cheap signed certificates for $10-20 a year, which is a trivial cost to protect your users.

However, if this is just a personal project (the only data you have to worry about is *yours*), or any data that you will be sending is freely available, a self-signed certificate may be enough.