# Download a file from server using HTPPS Protocol

Tags: iphone

I want to download a file from server using https protocol I am using NSUrlConnection but that would not work.any sample code is appreciated

Comment: Did you check out this question on stackoverflow: [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which is a great library for handling web services. You can of course roll your own with NSURLConnection, but the advantage of the library is that it handles all the authentication and certificate issues that can arise and generally gives you a more robust and generic solution.

Post some code if you'd rather not use the library, I suspect it might be you are accessing a site that doesn't have a fully valid certificate as IIRC the default behaviour of the iOS is to reject the certificates unless you explicitly allow them as this is the more secure option.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)
,Use it for network related stuff. Really useful.