# Https request is not working in iPhone device

Tags: iphone, https, request

I have to load all the required details from server in my application. eg; I wants to load countries detail from the following URL.

https://sub.domain.com//members/phone/XML_list_countries.php

But I am getting following error. But the same request working in Simulator.

**ERROR**
`Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x3b8d10 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://secure.nymgo.com//members/softphone/XML_list_countries.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://secure.nymgo.com//members/softphone/XML_list_countries.php, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x3b5090 "The request timed out."}`

**CODE**

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://secure.nymgo.com//members/softphone/XML_list_countries.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLConnection *_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_request delegate:self];
if(!_connection){
    NSLog(@"Can not make this request.");
}
```

I have implemented all the required `delegate` methods.

**NOTE:** My device is working in Wifi with proxy settings.

I don't know what is going wrong. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I checked with HTTP request, it is working fine in device. But HTTPS is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the same code in different `iPhone 3G` and `iPhone 4` devices. it is working fine.

**NOTE:** I searched lot in google. I got lot of result. One of the result is like "some `iPhone 3G` is not supporting for `HTTPS`. So I decided to test it in different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you Implement :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

Also Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert) SO post.

You can use the `ASIHTTPRequest` framework also.