# URL Schema in iPad for Kiosk type WebApp - Need to have Callback

Tags: ipad, callback, mobile-safari, kiosk-mode

Developing a Kiosk Type of the Application for iPad.

So Application flow is like i have one WebApp which runs like Kiosk(i.e it is full screen app)
and now i have one Button which Call my Native App 'CameraApp', takes an photo and upload to web.

NOW, wanted to return back to same Kiosk App or Open another URL in Kiosk already running in Background(this is either inactive or background running App).

I want to start that App in stack from the Current Stack in IOS. Is it Possible, How to Achieve it?

Background is a WebApp(Kiosk Mode) which invokes native App, now i want to jump back to the Old App. Tell me any workaround of achieving the same.

Help me out in Same. THanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your WebApp being delivered in an iOS app or just in Safari on the iPad?

If it is an app then you can register a custom URL scheme for it and then invoke that from the camera app.

If it is just Safari then you can just launch the http: URL and return that way.

If you are using a custom URL scheme to launch your camera app you can even use that to pass information on the URL that it should return to.

Either way, the URLs can be actioned with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];`

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477928/how-to-open-a-website-using-safari-in-fullscreen-mode-for-ipad) you can't control the full-screen presentation from the client side - your web site needs to use the appropriate meta tag - see ["Hiding Safari User Interface Components"](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2)

Comment: Yup same i am doing but above line :                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; will open in safari again that is not wanted, my WebApp is like full Screen travel through few Pages than ll land in Camera PAge and back i want in FULL Screen mode on Opening URL, thats not happening. so how to achieve it.

Comment: So, I think your question is actually "how do I launch Safari in Kiosk mode from another App?" - See my updated answer

Comment: I tried it with a test web site and, unfortunately, it doesn't seem that you can launch back into a full screen web site

Comment: thanks @Paulw11. So that approach is ruled out for me. so is there any way for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604320/kiosk-app-in-ios-can-we-provide-any-identifer-to-that-app-to-use-from-url-scheme , approach.