# Kiosk App in iOS can we provide any identifer to that app to use from URL scheme.

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme, kiosk-mode

I wanted, to give some identifier to the app that we create like a kiosk mode in iOS.

**i.e.** We make add to home screen and it has an icon on home page which browse further.

Is there any way, where I can give some identifier Name to that link of app getting created so that we can get that app access from our Native and we can provide URL Scheme for the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

iOS will not give access of all the url schemas. You can refer this document where the url schemas for selected application is given :

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Phone

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the only way you can achieve what you want to do is to build an app around an iOS UIWebView.  You can then include the camera functionality directly in the app, although there can be issues as a UIWebview doesn't handle things like popups that Safari does.