# HTTPS request fails only on iOS, Ionic 2

Tags: api, spring-boot, https, ionic2

I have an `Ionic 2` application that calls a `Spring Boot` API to send push notifications to other devices. The API is configured with HTTPS.

The API `POST` request works on everything **except** `iOS`.

My SSL certificate on the server is self signed (maybe that's it?).

Works on:

- ionic serve
- Android
- Postman
- curl

Here is the request:

```
public sendNotificationRequest(title: string, action: string, name: string, tokens: any, notifications: boolean) {
    // Check if user turned off notifications
    if(!notifications) {
        return;
    }

    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(this.username_decrypted + ':' + this.password_decrypted));
    let body = this.formObj(tokens, title, action, name);
    console.log(body);

    this.http.post("https://<some-url>",
                    body, { headers: headers }
    ).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log("HTTPS RESPONSE");
        console.log(response);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("HTTPS ERROR");
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

The header responses are as follows:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
```

And the this error is received:

```
{
 "_body":
    {"isTrusted":true},
    "status":0,"ok":false,
    "statusText":"",
    "headers":{},
    "type":3,
    "url":null
}
```

Spring Boot API:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value="/notifications", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<NotificationParent> sendNotifications(@RequestBody NotificationParent objs) {
    ...
    return new ResponseEntity<NotificationParent>(objs, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I am assuming its an iOS security issue, but I have no idea.

Comment: Try this - http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your assumption is correct-- an iOS security issue. In iOS there is something called App Transport Security that disallows, by default, connections over HTTP and connections with self-signed certificates.

You have to add

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

to the `Info.plist` of your project to allow your self-signed traffic.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189728) as well as the below links for more info.

http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/

https://gist.github.com/mlynch/284699d676fe9ed0abfa

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: @theblindprophet can you share the error message you're getting in the Console of the iOS app?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the console output of the physical/simulator iOS device when the app attempts the request.

Comment: @theblindprophet glad you were able to get things working :)

Comment: @theblindprophet would you mind accepting my answer as the Answer to your question?

Answer (score 4):

I had a same problem too. Removing the WkWebView solves the issue.

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
```

More info:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios10-http-requests-blocked/67663/2?u=profitsventure

After this plugin removed I can make http request via iOS

Comment: How did that help you? Was it the same problem as mentioned in the question?

Comment: @zubair1024 try this http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/

Comment: Similarly, I had to run 'ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
' to get our app working again with the latest Ionic CLI. Sweet Christmas Ionic development is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devices, the default WebViewEngine always uses CORS, to disable it temporarily, add the `<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />` to the `config.xml`. However, the downgrading to `UIWebViewEngine` has bad performance. Solving it in the server side is the right solution.

The HTTP server should be configured to have the right response to the CORS OPTIONS preflight request. The key point is that the Access-Control-Allow-Headers can not be “*” and should include any custom headers used in your app. Below is my setting that works:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, MyCustomHeader`

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to use `@ionic-native/http` instead of `@angular/http`.

Ionic native HTTP docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Here's what lead me to that workaround https://blog.ionicframework.com/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/

Comment: Where do we place the certificate file for ios?

Comment: Why do you think you need a certificate?  If you need one specifically for your iOS app, you'd have to place it in the Xcode project separately.  But without knowing the error that led you there it's hard to know which kind of certificate it is.

Comment: I already have one for our server which is a self signed. If I place it in xcode it is giving error for pinned certificate.

Comment: The problem is when trying to enable ssl pinning, the pinned certificate is not found even when included at proper location in project.