# NSMutableURLRequest checking for Https SSL certificate validation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios4

I am trying to utilize ssl for my application and apparently I don't notice that NSURLConnection is throwing any exception when using https with self signed cert. I am curious what might be the possibilities for not validating cert? I am sniffing the packets and it is using https port to bypass the transaction, but don't encounter the exception somehow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the cert is self-signed then it isn't actually a trusted https cert. If you want to bypass it use the code snippet at:

[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Comment: shawn, the concern is its getting bypassed and not throwing exception at all. Thats wht I am concerned why its not throwing an error.

Comment: Have you already implemented the delegate methods ie canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace and let it pass through?

Comment: Shawn, no I  haven't and I am making sure other delegates are being called of connection as well. The concern here is, I am actually making a call to a WCF based machine, its not a website, so just curious will that be a concern?