# iphone: didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace are not called for secure restful service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ssl

I am trying to get data from a secure restful service. I follow many other posts alongwith

[How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

But in my case didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge and canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace are not get called.

please help if you could solve the problem or provide me some good example to call secure restful service.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://76.69.53.126:8443/jaxrs/tdgateway/getCountries"];


NSError * error = nil;   
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: urlRequest returningResponse: nil error: &error ];

NSLog(@"This is %@",url);




- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    NSLog(@"This is canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace");
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"This is didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be different than `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust`, so just try this to start:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}
```

You should not cancel it immediately:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"This is didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");
    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *XAPIKEY = @"myapikey";
NSString *LOGINUSER = @"login username";
NSString *LOGINPASS = @"passwords";

// Setup NSURLConnection
- (void) postRequest:(NSString *) requestFun requestData:(NSDictionary *) sendDataDic{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://api.domain.com/index.php/api/", requestFun]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:XAPIKEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-API-KEY"];
    if(sendDataDic != nil){
        NSString *stringData = [self urlEncodedString:sendDataDic];
        [request setHTTPBody:[stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[stringData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    }
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void) getRequest:(NSString *) requestFun requestData:(NSDictionary *) sendDataDic{

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://api.domain.com/index.php/api/", requestFun]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:XAPIKEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-API-KEY"];

    if(sendDataDic != nil){
        NSString *stringData = [self urlEncodedString:sendDataDic];
        [request setHTTPBody:[stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[stringData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    }
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];

}

static NSString *toString(id object) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", object];
}

static NSString *urlEncode(id object) {
    NSString *string = toString(object);
    return [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

-(NSString*) urlEncodedString:(NSDictionary*) ObjDic {
    NSMutableArray *parts = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (id key in ObjDic) {
        id value = [ObjDic objectForKey: key];
        NSString *part = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@", urlEncode(key), urlEncode(value)];
        [parts addObject: part];
    }
    return [parts componentsJoinedByString: @"&"];
}

// NSURLConnection Delegates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:LOGINUSER
                                                                    password:LOGINPASS
                                                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSLog(@"response status code: %ld", (long)[httpResponse statusCode]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strData);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
   NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
}
```