# How to assign a .cer file in AFNetworking?

Tags: ssl, https, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to develop iPhone application that establish HTTPS connections ,I want use self-signed cert or trusted cert I can define ,but I cannot find any function(API) in AFNetworking can do this.

And I saw this page : [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823) .But I want to know how to assign a cer file?

Thanks.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17267088/192819

Answer (score 3):

Well, just to be simple, follow this steps

1. **Copy your .cer file to your project bundle**
2. **Assuming you are using**

   `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] init...`

   Invoke the following after that line:

   `[operation setSSLPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate]`

This will instruct AF to do Certificate Pinning, no need to set anything else.

Comment: I don't understand how AFNetworking knows which certificate to check against

Comment: Your app adds the certs it founds to the chain of thrust, it is made automatically...

Comment: Using AFNetworking 2.3.1 I don't see the method `setSSLPinningMode`

Comment: Using 2.5 version, i don't see the method setSSLPinningMode

Answer (score 2):

Just copy cer file in your project bundle.
In `AFURLConnectionOperation.m` file, line 215:

`NSArray *paths = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"cer" inDirectory:@"."];`

It will assign cer file automatically.

And make sure that Prefix.pch has follows:

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_
```

and

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_
```

if untrusted cert.

Comment: Wich Prefix should have the line??? i'm using Pods so having two, Application-Prefix.pch && AFNetworking-Prefix.pch ..

Comment: Application-Prefix.pch