# AFNetworking Issue: serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, django, afnetworking

I'm currently setting up an iOS app using Django Rest framework for the backend API. I am getting a -1011, request not found error when the url I'm using clearly exists.

The console outputs:

```
Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" 
UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response<NSHTTPURLResponse:0x12d797940> 

{ URL: https://myurl.com/users/login/ } 
{ status code: 404, headers {
    Allow = "POST, OPTIONS";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Thu, 06 Aug 2015 04:12:34 GMT";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.12 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept,Cookie";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} }, 

NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://myurl.com/users/login/, 
com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226d73 67223a22 536f7272 792c2079 6f757220 75736572 6e616d65 2c656d61 696c206f 72207061 7373776f 72642069 7320696e 636f7272 6563742e 227d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)}
2015-08-06 00:12:35.070 Tumvi[10963:3903454] Failed To Login
```

I've tested the endpoint using Rest client extension on chrome and as I mention before, the exact same code on the simulator IOS8.4 and another non-ios9 phone ran without any issues.

Honestly, I can't seem to figure out what might be the issue. Appreciate your help!

Comment: The error can't be more descriptive. `404` means there is nothing to serve in url:`https://myurl.com/users/login/`

Comment: That's what baffles me, on any other device the same code, the same url does serve properly. I even copied the exact url into Advanced Rest Client and was able to get the correct request.

Comment: you must set *security* policy for your manager. go check it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695625/afhttprequestoperation-with-self-signed-ssl-and-http-basic-auth-1012-error

Answer (score 0):

i hope it help you.

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];  //AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```