# Possible dynamic SSL Cert Pinning?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, ssl, ssl-certificate

Correct me if I'm wrong, SSL cert pinning on mobile simply means that backend(Party A) has a cert and this cert we are included in our mobile apps(Party B), and whenever we want to firing network request, the request and response will be encrypted and decrypted by both parties on the agreed cert.

Now the funny thing is, backend(Party B) is having another vendor(Party C) managing the certs for them, and Party C has the rights to manage the certs however they want to. In other words, it's like a dynamic SSL cert instead of static certs. In this scenario, it's not really possible for my mobile apps to implement cert pinning between my mobile apps and backend(Party A) right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot handle said scenario. You would have to update Party B each time Party C decides to change cert of Party A.

related question: [Dynamic certificate pinning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498671/dynamic-certificate-pinning)