# HTTPS post request in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to make https post request by using following code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://portkey.formspring.me/login/"];

//initialize a request from url
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url       standardizedURL]];

//set http method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//initialize a post data

NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"username", @"username",
                          @"password", @"password", nil];

NSError *error=nil;

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted     error:&error];



[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set post data of request
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

//initialize a connection from request
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

//start the connection
[connection start];
```

But im getting following response.

> error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “portkey.formspring.me” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x7564180 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://portkey.formspring.me/login/, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending >to be “portkey.formspring.me” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0x7168a20 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “portkey.formspring.me” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=}

Can anybody tell me how to make post request using NSURLConnection??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to fix it on the server side

Comment: The error answers your question, the server is not who they say they are (as far as iOS is concerned)

Comment: Their certificate has been expired for a while, so I assume they are aware of it. Are you sure you are connecting to the right URL?

Answer (score 7):

The certificate for the site you're trying to connect to is untrusted (try visiting the link you posted in Chrome).

By default, iOS won't let you connect to site that presents an untrusted certificate. You can bypass this check if absolutely necessary - see this question: [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823)

However, it's going to much, much, much better to actually fix the certificate in question.

Answer (score 0):

These Delegate Methods of `NSURLConnection` are **Deprecated**

```
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didCancelAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

You can use `-connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` instead of these 3 *Deprecated* Methods

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust)
    {
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:[[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust]] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```