# NSURLSession + HTTPS is any other setup needed?

Tags: ssl, ios7, https, nsurlsession

I'm sending with POST some data to server using `NSURLSession`, I did it over HTTP, now I had to change to HTTPS. To my pleasant surprise all is working fine, which means that all I did was changing url from http to https. 
But is it enough? Should I take any additional steps? Is it secured? The server has SSL certificate.

Comment: Better you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918697/https-post-request-in-ios.

Comment: Thanks, this is about the invalid/untrusted certificate - but this is not the issue in my case as the certificate is valid and trusted (not self signed). I was wondering only if anything related to HTTPS/SSL communication then is handled transparently to me - as all I did was changing the protocol to HTTPS and all is working:) but is it secure:)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same question/concern.