# NSURLSession and HTTPS

Tags: https, nsurlsession

I have an app that uses NSURLSession to run .php files on a web server.  The directory on the web server is password protected and the didReceiveChallenge delegate is working perfectly, returning the user name and password.  Up until now this has all been over HTTP as it has simply been a proof of concept, and is therefore open to man-in-the-middle threats.

As I near completion I am going to switch to HTTPS using a trusted cert and am wondering what additional steps I need to take (if any) with NSURLSession to communicate with a secure connection, or will it be as simple as switching the url in the session from HTTP to HTTPS once the server is setup.  This will NOT be a self signed cert.

I have found similar questions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864622/nsurlsession-https-is-any-other-setup-needed?rq=1), but none that have an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and installed a self signed certificate on my web server, and then simply changed the HTTP to HTTPS in NSURLRequest and all seems to be working just fine!