# Consume Secure Web Service (https) in an Iphone App(Objective C)

Tags: objective-c

I have a working web service, which is not secure(http), I try to connect to it from my iphone app and its works!!. I want to make this web service secure, so created a self signing certificate from IIS and has the service use it. I now have a secure web service with https and now I want my app to access this secure web service and I am drawing a blank.

The following is the code I used to access the unsecured web service, could you please provide me with a simple option to access the secure web service, just changing the URL to https doesn't work.

```
(XXXXXSessionDispatcher *) sessionForLoginDict: (NSDictionary *)loginDict
                                        serviceHost: (NSString *)serviceHost
{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"httpsxxx%@/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/OpenSession",serviceHost];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:loginDict options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

return [[XXXXXSessionDispatcher alloc] initFromJSONString:urlString jsonString:jsonString];
}
```

Comment: You are *not* showing the code that accesses the web service. Anyway, in order to handle self signed certificates and if you use NSURLConnection, you absolutely need to implement the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that iOS does not accept self signed certificates. Depending on the class/method you use for connecting to the service there are different ways setting your code so that it will accept the self signed certificate.

Also, when doing this, make sure this code only runs in debug mode else you will be shipping insecure code.

Maybe this helps:
[NSURLConnection with SSL for untrusted cert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

Comment: Are you sure the link is the answer to the question? As far as I can see, this handles the case for more or less ignoring an untrusted cert from the server. Just for test code, NOT for production. IMHO, if you want to actually check against the cert, you should perform a few additional steps.