# SSL certificate FQDN for REST web service at a specific path

Tags: ios, authentication, openssl, ssl-certificate, fqdn

I was using iOS to connect to a server using a certificate whose CN (commonname) and FQDN (fully qualified domain name) is `server.myexample.com`. The server certificate was signed by my own Root CA (whose certificate I added to my anchor certs via `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates` and verified via the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert) using `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge`).

With my iOS client, I was attempting to connect my REST service located at: `server.myexample.com/Path1/service1`, but I kept receiving the following error:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server
that is pretending to be “server.myexample.com” which could put your confidential
information at risk.

Error occurred while fetching https://server.myexample.com/Path1/service1: Error
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. 
You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “server.myexample.com” 
which could put your confidential information at risk."
```

I get additional messages with the same info but specifying the errors: `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey` and `NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey`.

I found that I could also call the service with `server.myexample.com/service1` and removed Path1 from my request URL, and the server certificate verification worked correctly.  Why is this?  I was under the impression that the server only needed 1 certificate, meaning any services it hosts would also be using that same certificate.  Maybe you need a separate server certificate per path?  I was not aware the paths after the server ip address/domain needed to have their own certificate.

To summarize:

- iOS client app with Root CA certificate in the anchor certs
- Server `server1`'s certificate signed by Root CA has a CN of `server.myexample.com` and whose FQDN is `https://server.myexample.com`.
- Server `server.myexample.com` hosts `service1` which can be accessed by web browser via:

  - `https://server.myexample.com/service1`  (passes iOS client's authentication of server)
  - `https://server.myexample.com/Path1/service1`  (FAILS iOS client's authentication of server)
- CA and server certificates were created via OpenSSL

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The certificate is presented by the server before the path is provided, so it should not matter. when you call https://server.myexample.com/service1, do you receive HTTP 200?

Comment: Initially the app was stopping at the failed authentication (since I didn't have it continue with failed authentication). I presume it would be 200 if I let it continue through (similar to using `[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:myRequest.URL.host];` which allowed me to receive the response without verifying the server). However, I just tried the Path1 request again, and it worked fine this time, so maybe the issue was server-side? I will test some more and see if I get consistent results again.

Comment: @aspergillusOryzae It has been long but, can you please guide me what was the solution that time for you for this issue ?

Comment: @Mrunal It has been a while, but I believe that the issue was resolved with the server refreshing it's certificate (possibly due to caching). I don't believe I ran into additional issues after that. Possibly try restarting your server and ensuring that the server side cert is as expected.