# OS X Server & NSAppTransportSecurity HTTP load failed

Tags: ssl, swift2, osx-server

I'm using OS X Server 4.1.3 and  an iPhone 6 with iOS9 Beta-4.

When I try to connect to the OS X Server ("skw.local") with

```
let urlPath: String = "https://skw.local/"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let sesh = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
let task = sesh.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) -> Void in
     if error == nil {
          print("Response: \(response)")
     }
     else {
          print(error, appendNewline: true)
     }
}
task.resume()
```

I get the following error:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “skw.local” which could put your confidential information at risk."
```

I have tried bypassing the NSAppTransportSecurity requirements by adding the following to my Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

but I get the same errors.

Anyone else having similar trouble?

edit: I also posted this over on apple's dev [forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12747)

Comment: Does it work with the previous SDKs?  Thanks

Comment: Yes I've connected to the OS X Server with Swift 1.2 in the past, with a self-signed certificate installed on the dev device.  But now I have a few devices that I'm testing the app on, and wanted to avoid needing to install the cert on each one.

Comment: Can't test it myself, but does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32770621/2494219