# NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed error (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9, xcode7, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession in my application to send the data to server. Server URL may be arbitary , It may change dynamically

So I have added following in my plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

because user can change the server URL manually from settings page inside my application. So when I try to send data  , NSURLRequest will be configured with latest server URL.

My code is

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

//some of my codes

 }] resume];
```

I will create NSMutableURLRequest from dynamic URL which is entered by user in settings page(eg. https://100.100.25.25/sample).

```
NSMutableURLRequest *dataRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serverAddress 
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

when I try to access the server using NSURLSession with latest server URL then
Its always return error "NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)".

Note : If my URL only contain characters(https://sample.com/sample) then its working fine. If it contains some number(https://100.100.25.25/sample) then its not working.
Given URL is not live. Its just to say
Please help me to find the issue . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. Source : [How do I accept a self-signed SSL certificate using iOS 7's NSURLSession and its family of delegate methods for development purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507207/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-ios-7s-nsurlsession-and-its)

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:Nil];
...
...
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
  if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"mydomain.com"]){
      NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
      completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }
  }
}
```