# Swift SSL error with self signed certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ssl

This code attempts and fails to access an SSL URL which works in a browser:

```
let path = "https://localhost:8443/greeting"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
    if let c = json["content"].string {
        print(c)
    }
})
task.resume()
```

Fails with the error:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has
>   occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."
>   UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=,

What is required to allow the app to accept this cert?

The certificate in question is self signed.  Read a few solutions on SO without success.

Running Xcode 7.2

Comment: Did you trust the certificate? Like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507207/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-ios-7s-nsurlsession-and-its

Comment: Is it the issue of ATS ? Please check your plist. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32955793/3202193

Comment: @skyline75489 - I tried - updated the question.

Comment: Thanks Ashish that was the key!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

@Ashish Kakkad was spot on.  This works:

```
class Blah: NSURLSessionDelegate {

    func rest() {
        let path = "https://localhost:8443/greeting"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
            if let c = json["content"].string {
                print(c)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
}
```

With this in the Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: This works, but is only a workaround. Also please notice that Exceptions made with ATS soon will be deprecated.

Comment: I also got news from fellow devs .. that apple doesn't allow apps in app store with this setting on.

Comment: This solution simply ignores the certificate altogether, rather than trying to confirm the user is using the self-signed certificate.

Comment: This is not a solution. By doing it this way you are not protected for MITM attack. You are approving all certs, without checking if the cert is valid.

Answer (score 17):

Sai Reddy's solution allows you to accept your self-signed certificate if it has a complete chain, but it also accepts others.

Marcus Leon's solution is a complete override -- basically ignoring all certificates.

I like this one better.

**Swift 4.1, iOS 11.4.1**

First, in your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Second, wherever you use your NSURLSession, instead of setting up with URLSession.shared, use something like this:

```
session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: APIURLSessionTaskDelegate(isSSLPinningEnabled: isSSLPinningEnabled), delegateQueue: nil)
```

Then add this class to handle pinning:

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        print("*** received SESSION challenge...\(challenge)")
        let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)

        guard isSSLPinningEnabled else {
            print("*** SSL Pinning Disabled -- Using default handling.")
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
            return
        }

        let myCertName = "my_certificate_to_pin"
        var remoteCertMatchesPinnedCert = false
        if let myCertPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: myCertName, ofType: "der") {
            if let pinnedCertData = NSData(contentsOfFile: myCertPath) {
                // Compare certificate data
                let remoteCertData: NSData = SecCertificateCopyData(SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0)!)
                if remoteCertData.isEqual(to: pinnedCertData as Data) {
                    print("*** CERTIFICATE DATA MATCHES")
                    remoteCertMatchesPinnedCert = true
                }
                else {
                    print("*** MISMATCH IN CERT DATA.... :(")
                }

            } else {
                print("*** Couldn't read pinning certificate data")
            }
        } else {
            print("*** Couldn't load pinning certificate!")
        }

        if remoteCertMatchesPinnedCert {
            print("*** TRUSTING CERTIFICATE")
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
        } else {
            print("NOT TRUSTING CERTIFICATE")
            completionHandler(.rejectProtectionSpace, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This class checks to see if you enabled certificate pinning.  If you did, it completely ignores the normal certificate validation and does an exact comparison with the cert we include in the app.  In this way, it **only** accepts your self-signed cert, and nothing else.

This solution requires that you put a "**my_certificate_to_pin.der**" file in your project, in your Resources folder.  If you don't already have a Resources folder, just add one.

That certificate should be in DER format.

To create a self-signed certificate for your server, you would normally do something like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.key -out mycert.cer
```

That generates two files -- a **mycert.key** private key file, and a **mycert.cer** -- the certificate itself.  These are both in the X509 format.  For iOS, you will need the cert in DER format, so do this:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in mycert.cer -out my_certificate_to_pin.der
```

That generates the file you need on iOS.

Comment: What if I want to simply allow ALL certs while in the simulator? Is there something I can add in my code when compiling for it?

Comment: Just stick "completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)" after the first two let statements ("let trust ...", and "let credential..."), and it will accept everything.

Comment: Usually that's because the cert isn't in DER format.  See the openssl commands above.

Comment: This worked first time. Why isn't it the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

you can use your own certificates instead of my certificates(fullchain.pem)

```
    class AccessingServer: NSObject,URLSessionDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
            // First load our extra root-CAs to be trusted from the app bundle.
            let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust

            let rootCa = "fullchain"
            if let rootCaPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: rootCa, ofType: "pem") {
                if let rootCaData = NSData(contentsOfFile: rootCaPath) {

                    let rootCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, rootCaData)!

                    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust!, [rootCert] as CFArray)

                    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(trust!, false)
                }
            }

            var trustResult: SecTrustResultType = SecTrustResultType.invalid
            SecTrustEvaluate(trust!, &trustResult)

            if (trustResult == SecTrustResultType.unspecified ||
                trustResult == SecTrustResultType.proceed) {
                // Trust certificate.

                let credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
                challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)

            } else {
                NSLog("Invalid server certificate.")
                challenge.sender?.cancel(challenge)
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("Got unexpected authentication method \(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)");
            challenge.sender?.cancel(challenge)
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: From where to get the certificate?

Comment: #Rajesh certificates are provided by the backend team

Comment: I exported the certificate from keychain. I got crash at this line SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust!, rootCert as! CFArray).

Comment: To avoid getting null from SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40155587/seccertificatecreatewithdata-always-returning-null

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.1**

I know you found the answer but I have an shorter way to this if anyone can use it

```
class AuthViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

func login(username: String, password: String,completion: @escaping ((LoginModel) -> Void)) -> Void {
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://YourAPI.xyz/APP/?action=login&user=\(username)&pass=\(password)")!

    // Here is Important ****
    let req = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    // *****

    let task = req.dataTask(with: request) { data1, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data1,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil
        else {                                                               // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error", error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
            return
        }
        
        guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {                    // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }
        
        // do whatever you want with the `data`, e.g.:
        
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                let resStreing = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                let resData = resStreing?.data(using: .utf8)
                
                let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginModel.self, from: resData!)
                
                print("\n\n ResponseObject = \(responseObject) \n\n")
                completion(responseObject)
            } catch {
                print("CAN NOT PARSE!") // parsing error
                
                if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
                } else {
                    print("unable to parse response as string")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
  }
}
```

The extension which you need:

```
extension AuthViewModel: URLSessionDelegate {
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
   //Trust the certificate even if not valid
   let urlCredential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)

   completionHandler(.useCredential, urlCredential)
}
}
```

And usage:

```
authviewModel.login(username: "UserName",password: "Password") { loginModel in
// Do something
}
```