# Swift - The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: ios, swift, server, request, invalidation

How can I fix this on iOS using Swift? When I'm making a server request I get the following error:

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “...” which could put your confidential information at risk.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to **install the certificates on the iOS simulators**

[image]

---

From [Charles Documentation](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/):

> Quit your iOS Simulator. Launch Charles and go to the Help menu.
>   Choose the "SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS
>   Simulators" item. This will install your Charles Root Certificate into
>   all of your iOS Simulators. Now when you start the iOS Simulator, you
>   should be able to access SSL websites with Charles using SSL Proxyin

Comment: Wonderful.!! Thank you

Comment: @Enrique I am new to using charles proxy. If i follow this, my internet itself stops working. I am unable to test the app on iOS Simulator. Pls suggest

Comment: This works with Proxyman too!

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably trying to connect to server with self-signed ssl certificate. iOS does not like it.
Take a look at this post as an example: [Swift SSL error with self signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592572/swift-ssl-error-with-self-signed-certificate). 
Other possible issue is a proxy configuration with something like Charles behind it.
More details will maybe help to identify the root of the issue...

Comment: My app is running fine until the iOS 13. I got this error when testing with iOS 13. Any suggestion? Is there anyway to bypass this error because I can't touch the server certificate now.

Comment: You can try to implement `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)` method of the `URLSessionDelegate` overriding default behaviour.

Comment: I'm using Alamofire to call rest api. Is there a way to bypass this error? Thanks.

Comment: @Bagusflyer do you find the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Simple change your device time zone to automatically time zone. This resolve your issue.