# Allow NSArbitraryLoads in app info.plist disables TLS completely or just allows insecure connection

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I have an app which uses 4 to 5 third party libraries and one of the library is deprecating the support less than TLS 1.2. So I just want to know, if I add NSArbitraryLoads flag, it will disable TLS1.2 version itself completely for all requests Or it will make TLS1.2 connection to the server which supports the TLS1.2.

Answer (score 0):

NSArbitraryLoads just allow insecure connection. It doesn't remove TLS requirement.

If you want to remove this requirement check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507207/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-ios-7s-nsurlsession-and-its)