# Getting error with NSURLSession "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)"

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

This question looks duplicate, I have searched solution for problem.
Few of them suggested, after applying below suggestion still not work

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

My code worked with **NSURLConnection** . Server send response

```
    -(NSMutableURLRequest *) getRequest
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://URLRequest"];
    NSString *requestBody = @"username=abc&password=pqr@2&deviceId=646D4945-DA22-408B-B132-EFDED5430650&deviceTypeId=1&deviceName=iPad Simulator&versionInfo=Version 1.16.6 1.0.13";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //NSData *paramData = [requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:[requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request addValue:@"1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HTTP"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    return request;
}

-(void) sessionRequest
{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[self getRequest]
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {

                           if(data)
                           {
                               NSError *jsonError = nil;
                               id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
                               if (jsonError)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Problem for download data");   
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"Response:%@",json);
                               }
                           }                      
                       }];
}
```

I get message **NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed** with **NSURLSession**

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
//NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:[self getRequest]
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  NSHTTPURLResponse *tempResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                  NSLog(@"statusCode:%d %@",tempResponse.statusCode,tempResponse.allHeaderFields);
                                  if(data)
                                  {
                                      NSError *jsonError = nil;
                                      id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
                                      if (jsonError)
                                      {
                                          NSLog(@"Problem for download data");   
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          NSLog(@"Response:%@",json);
                                      }
                                  }
                              }];

[task resume];
```

Have anyone faced issue.Please guide.

Comment: Just to clarify, it works with NSURLConnection in the same version of the OS?

Comment: Yes it works with same version iOS9.3 simulator and iPad devices.

Comment: Try the answer mentioned in the the below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704663/getting-error-with-nsurlsession-nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed?noredirect=1#comment66711430_39704663

Comment: Thank you @friherd, solution suggested in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507207/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-ios-7s-nsurlsession-and-its