# IOS: Difference between proposedCredentials and URLCredential for trust

Tags: ios, security, urlsession, trust, authenticationchallenge

In [`URLSession:task:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate/1411595-urlsession), is there a difference between using [`.proposedCredential`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlauthenticationchallenge/1417749-proposedcredential) vs [`URLCredential(trust:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcredential/1413935-init) of the server trust object in the challenge protection space?

This is to pass back as the second parameter in the completion handler of the delegate method, along with [`.useCredentials`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/authchallengedisposition/usecredential).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer received here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/361609

> Realistically there’s no difference here.  For server trust authentication challenges, the system does not actually look at the trust object embedded in the credential you pass to the completion handler; all that matters is that you pass in something.
>
> Having said that, I recommend that you stick on the well-trodden path and construct a new credential.  I’m actually quite surprised that `proposedCredential` is even populated in this case.