# https connection fails on iOS device

Tags: ios, ssl, https, nsurlconnection

I had an error with connecting to the server: `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “...” which could put your confidential information at risk."`. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert). But it works only for simulator. And when I test on my iOS device, it cannot connect to the server. What is not correct? Can someone help me?

Comment: No, the *error* reported by the system *is* the case when it works. The link describes how to *disable* server trust evaluation. This is the same as when you don't have the right key for a secure lock and you cannot get it, and the link now describes how you can remove the lock in order that it "works for you" ;)  There are *correct* solutions for your issue, though. You just need to describe your requirements and your scenario.

Comment: ok, but is there any difference between the requests I made from simulator and from iOS device? Because I don't have device with me and cannot test it. I just send archive file to client and he tests it.

Comment: Well, yes. There can also be differences between different devices: for example: there might be a root certificate installed on one device which is used to verify the server's certificate. On others this might not be installed. There are other reasons, too. You need to describe the scenario and your security requirements for a possible approach to solve that issue. And of course, your *code* where you handle the authentication request.