# How to use Charles Proxy on the Xcode 6 (iOS 8) Simulator?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, ios-simulator, charles-proxy

It seems that the directory for the iOS Simulator has changed. It used to be in `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/` and now it's in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`.

Answer (score 121):

**Update: [Charles 3.9.3+](http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/) has a built-in function to configure your iOS Simulators (i.e. installing the Charles SSL Certificate). This can be found in the Help menu within the Charles application. (`Help > SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators`)**

*The following applies to Charles 3.9.2:*

Download the [configuration shell script](http://www.charlesproxy.com/assets/install-charles-ca-cert-for-iphone-simulator.zip) from the [Charles Proxy website](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/). Then, replace the script with the following, and run it on your Mac:

```
#/bin/bash
install() {
if [ -f "$SQLITEDBPATH" ]; then
cp -n "$SQLITEDBPATH" "$SQLITEDBPATH.charlesbackup"
sqlite3 "$SQLITEDBPATH" <<EOF
INSERT INTO "tsettings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
EOF
fi
}

for SQLITEDBPATH in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*/data/Library/Keychains/TrustStore.sqlite3; do
    echo $SQLITEDBPATH
    install
done

echo "The Charles SSL CA Certificate has been installed for the iPhone Simulator"
```

---

Some things to note:

- **you must open Charles before launching the simulator. If you close Charles, network requests will fail until you restart the simulator**
- you will need to do this every time you "Reset Content and Settings..." on the simulator
- For Xcode 5: if you're looking to setup Charles Proxy on Xcode 5 and earlier, you don't need to modify the original script. Just download it from the Charles website and run it as-is

Comment: Works after restarting simulator.

Comment: You answer seems to fix SSL request problem. but the main problem might be Charles doesn't handle any requests from iOS simulator 8.0/Xcode6
Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I think the script has been moved to here: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/ (and reading the source, it looks like it's been updated in the way you suggest)

Comment: I followed this but am seeing error in terminal - UNIQUE constraint failed: tsettings.sha1

Comment: FYI- I updated this answer to include instructions to download Charles 3.9.3 with does the certificate installation via its Help menu, rather than needing a script.

Comment: Anyone running Charles successfully proxying an iOS 11.0 (15A5361a) simulator?

Comment: I'm getting error "UnknownHost: api.staging.companyName.com" Response code 503. I've double checked the steps you mentioned. what may be going wrong here ?

Answer (score 35):

I just tested Charles over Xcode 7 / iOS9 simulator.  Just a few pointers I want to add if you're having trouble:

- Make sure "**Enable Mac OS proxy**" and "**Use HTTP Proxy**" are checked under
  Charles' Proxy | Proxy Settings;  and optionally check "**Enable Mac OS X
  proxy at startup**" if you don't want to do this step every time you
  start Charles.
- If your **Automatic Proxy Configuration** (and/or **Auto Proxy Discovery**) is set in your System
  Preferences | Network,  you need to uncheck it lest Charles' Web
  Proxy (HTTP) and Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS) will not take effect.
- If your company requires proxy server independent of Charles, you
  need to manually replicate the settings inside Charles lest they are overridden by Charles and you won't be able to access the internet. Make note of the proxy
  URL and port numbers before starting Charles.  Transcribe these **Web
  Proxy** and **Secure Web Proxy** settings under Charles' Proxy | External
  Proxy Settings.
- "**Enable SSL Proxying**" and add your endpoint on the list, via Charles'
  Proxy | SSL Proxying Settings.
- "**Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulator**" via Charles' Help
  | SSL Proxying menu.
- And yeah, make sure Charles is setup and started first before you
  start the simulator.
- Finally for now, disable ATS during development until we hear more
  from Apple.

Comment: "Finally for now, disable ATS during development until we hear more from Apple." - Spot on, missing from other answers above.

Comment: Thanks! They should put this on the Charles' website!

Comment: Charles supports App Transport Security (ATS) as of the 3.11.4 release.

Comment: +1 for **uncheck Automatic Proxy Configuration**. I have a .pac file in company network environment and simulator's traffic may not appear in Charles due to it.

Comment: **"Make sure "Enable Mac OS proxy" and "Use HTTP Proxy" are checked under Charles' Proxy | Proxy Settings"**  This help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

According to charles documentation

> The iOS Simulator should use the system proxy settings. If it doesn't, please try quitting and restarting the iOS Simulator. As of Xcode 6 it appears to be important that Charles is running and set as the Mac OS X system proxy before you run the iOS Simulator.

[Read Here](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/)

So just quit your simulator, open charles and then run the app again. After that you can track your network calls.

**NOTE:** Your network calls will fail if you quit Charles. So you will need to either quit the simulator and run it again or open Charles again.

Comment: I found that if you have an "autoconfigure" proxy URL set, Charles Proxy won't work. It seems that the autoconfigure URL overrides any manual proxy settings. Removing the auto-config URL, and specifying manual settings (with credentials, in my case) allowed Charles to reeconfigure the settings and it worked.. without even restarting the iOS Simulator (7.1).

Answer (score 12):

Another way to do it is to browse to the certificate http://charlesproxy.com/charles.crt on the device

which will present you with the screen:

[image: install certificate prompt screen]

Comment: I tried this method but it also failed to load secure site when running local server. Can anyone put some light on how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Try browsing using Safari to see if there is anything wrong with the certificate. To do this click on the lock symbol for your website.

[Safari certificate dialog window](http://imgur.com/LrUZkdA).

I suspect that you are using a certificate that is self-signed and that you need to install the client certificate on your machine. This can be achieved through Safari and by choosing Trust -> 'always allow'.

Comment: I had to do this to get rid of SSL Handshake errors.

Answer (score 4):

Update for iOS 9: You have to disable App Transport Security to use Charles!

http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/

Comment: Charles supports App Transport Security (ATS) as of the 3.11.4 release.

Answer (score 3):

**Steps for iOS simulator.**

- Install Charles - [download](https://www.charlesproxy.com/latest-release/download.do)
- Charles Menu -> Proxy -> **Enable Mac Proxy**
- Charles Menu -> Tools -> Proxy -> Proxy Settings -> MacOS -> Check all the check
  boxes
- Install Charles Certificate in iOS simulators
- Charles Menu -> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Ceritificate in iOS
  Simulators
- Enable Charles Certificate in iOS Simulators
- iOS Simulators Setttings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings -> **Switch
  On**
- If traffic does not appear, Run Charles before simulator

**Steps for iPhone/iPad.**

- Open desktop Charles app (Mac/Windows)
- Goto Charles Menu -> Help -> SSL Proxying -> Install Charles Ceritificate on a Mobile device or Remote browser -> Select -> popup appear with below steps
  `

  > Configure your device to use Charles as its HTTP Proxy on
  >   **192.168.0.100:8888**, then browser to **chls.pro/ssl** to download and install the certificate.
- Goto iPhone settings -> Wifi -> click selected wifi -> Http proxy -> Configure proxy -> select **Manual** -> Give server as 192.168.0.100 and port as 8888 -> **Save**
- Goto iPhone browser -> Load [chls.pro/ssl](https://chls.pro/ssl) -> It will show below popup
  `

  > The website is trying to download a configuration profile. Do you want to allow this? 
  >   Ignore button and **Allow** button
- Click **Allow** button -> It will download the profile
- Goto iPhone Settings -> General -> Profiles -> Downloaded Profile -> Select the Charles Proxy profile -> **Install**
- Goto iPhone Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings -> **Enable** - Charles Proxy CA certificate
- Now we can track the iPhone app calls in desktop Charles app

Comment: iOS Simulators Setttings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings -> Switch On what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I didnt see the  configuration shell script on that page. I did the following and it worked for me:

http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-the-charles-debugging-proxy-to-work-with-ios-and-genymotion/

Comment: This answer is better than @jonsibley's. The configuration script on Charles website is gone.

Comment: I think it's just been moved to here: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/

Answer (score 2):

**Check this out:**

> As of Charles v3.9.3 there is an item in the Help menu, "Install
>   Charles CA SSL Certificate in iOS Simulators", which will
>   automatically install Charles's SSL CA certificate in your iOS
>   Simulators.
>
> Alternatively, you can change your code so that NSURLConnection
>   accepts any SSL certificate. Please see the question and answer on
>   Stack Overflow:
>   [How to use NSURLConnection to connect with SSL for an untrusted cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert)

**You can check it on this link:** http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/

Answer (score 2):

The 'Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS simulators' does not work in the current version of CharlesProxy (3.11) with Xcode 7 / iOS 9 simulators.

Instead, use the 'Install Charles Root Certificate on a Mobile Device or Remote Browser...' option. This will give you a url for the certificate.

If you open this url in Safari in the simulator, you will then be given the option to install the certificate.

You still then need to disable app transport security. I don't understand why this is necessary when you have the certificate installed; I guess CharlesProxy does not use sufficiently large keys/signatures.

Comment: If nothing else, the cert is self-signed and for sure that's not gonna fly with Apple's ATS requirements. The first step is to have Charles' cert signed by a sanctioned Certificate Authority but logistics aside, it's going to cost money. Domain also has to be public facing. Etc. Etc.  It won't be easy if at all feasible.

Comment: @Hampden123 As far as I know, Apple's App Transport Security mechanism would allow a self signed certificate *so long as it has been installed correctly into the iOS device as a trusted certificate* - hence why I believe charlesproxy needs ATS disabling for a different reason. I can't seem to access the Apple ATS documentation currently to check this though.

Comment: If you (or anyone) are successful in serving self-signed certificate to an iOS 9 device without disabling ATS, please let me know how you do it. TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Just (re)starting the Simulator after Charles starts fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those who struggling with untrusted connections on Xcode 9 beta's simulators:

I don't know if install script works or not but you are able to install charles' cert in same way as on physical device - through Safari.

Last step that is needed (of course after installing certificate either through script or via Safari): Go to Simluator's settings -> general -> about -> Certificate trust settings -> Charles Proxy Custom Root... -> enable

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is what worked.

I did same thing as we do in device.

1. Open safari and browse chls.pro/ssl
2. Accept and install the certificate
3. Go to Settings/About/Trust certificates and trust the charles certificate.

I have to do this on 3 simulator instances, as XCUI automation testing can spin 3.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me after go to safari (simulator) and visit the URL:

```
chls.pro/ssl
```

Before I had to Install charles root certificate in iOS simulators (Charles: help/SSLproxying)

regards