# Charles for capturing iPhone traffic doesn't work on iOS8

Tags: ios, charles-proxy

After I have installed Xcode6/iOS Simulator(iOS8), Charles seems can't capture any requests from iOS Simulator. 
and Proxy-> Access Control Setting is clean. All Charles settings weren't be modified after upgraded Xcode6

Anybody has the same trouble ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439756/how-to-use-charles-proxy-on-the-xcode-6-ios-8-simulator

Comment: my bad. I have seem the post before , But I have ignored restart Simulator. thank you

Comment: @aelam - Is it working now? I have had a similar issue where the script didn't work even with a restart.  I fixed it by manually installing the certificate on the simulator.

Comment: @Robert yes copy the script and run it directly in terminal, then restart simulator. it works

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem because I use a proxy in my wifi connection to go though the FXK GFW. In this situation, some requests won't go through charles. 
You can check this out.