# How to use Charles Proxy on an Xcode Playground?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charles-proxy

When tying out network requests from a Swift playground, I can't see the network call in Charles Proxy. However, it works when I do network requests from an iOS simulator by following the steps in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439756/how-to-use-charles-proxy-on-the-xcode-6-ios-8-simulator).

Would be nice to make it work for Xcode Playgrounds for faster iteration. Does anyone know what needs to be done to make it work there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the simulator, Playgrounds don't have their own network configuration. If you need a proxy on a Playground then you need to proxy your Mac's network connection. That will affect every app on your Mac, which is potentially a lot of data. It should work but you might want to quit any other network-related apps that you can. If you don't need to use your browser while testing, for example, quit it until you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version of fruitcoder's answer:

```Swift
public class NetworkEnabler: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
}
```

Then to initialize the URLSession:

```Swift
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: NetworkEnabler(), delegateQueue: nil)
```

Comment: Is there something we can do to view decrypted contents?
For instance, we had to trust a Charles Proxy certificate on the real device when using that.

Comment: @BFeher Did you try `Enable SSL Proxy` in Charles for those requests?

Answer (score 1):

I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/shepting/829ff2f6940e71c0990c) that describes a way to make it work with Playgrounds. It circumvents the need to alter the ATS settings. Create an object conforming to `URLSessionDelegate` with the following implementation:

```swift
public class NetworkEnabler: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {
    public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
    }
}
```

and create a session with an instance as its delegate: `URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: enabler, delegateQueue: nil)`. Using that session for requests will allow you to use Charles.