# NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust validation for server certificate

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am handling https authentication for server based on its name but i want to trust server based on a certificate which server gives me. how can i do this ,any help ??

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
     isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
{
    // we only trust our own domain
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"www.serverpage.com"])
    {
        NSURLCredential *credential =
            [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

I searched web and found most of the answers are just accepting any server authentication without validating .

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you implementing the SSL handshake yourself? Can't you use a library like AFNetworking?

Comment: My app doent have AFNetworking , it uses only NSURLConnection.

Comment: My understanding was that `NSURLConnection` would do this by itself. Checking the server name is part of the default SSL handshake. Or are you trying to connect using a self signed certificate?

Comment: Yep, its self signed certificate checking

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need an encapsulate a server certificate inside your app.
When your app starts, you need to extract a Public Key from an encapsulated server certificate.
When run in delegate's callback  `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:challenge:completionHandler`
you need to iterate through obtained certificates from supplied `challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust`
and do comparation with Public Key you extracted before.

Best thing - also do the same with an Issuer certificate - include original of it in your app, and investigate it with obtained one from challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust

next code snippet is demonstrating an extraction of the Public Key from a certificate:

```
SecKeyRef getPKeyFromCert(SecCertificateRef cert) {
    SecTrustRef newtrust = NULL;
    CFMutableArrayRef certs = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    CFMutableArrayRef newPolicies = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    CFArrayAppendValue(certs, cert);

    if (SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certs, newPolicies, &newtrust) == errSecSuccess) {
        return SecTrustCopyPublicKey(newtrust);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

next code snippet is demonstrating an iteration through the certificates, supplied via the protectionSpace:

```
SecTrustRef trustRef = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
CFIndex count = SecTrustGetCertificateCount(trustRef);
CFIndex i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    SecCertificateRef certRef = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trustRef, i);
    SecKeyRef publicKey = getPKeyFromCert(certRef);
    // do the magic
}
```

Answer (score -1):

NSURLConnection has a builtin method for doing SSL with non trusted certs. See the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033823). Please make sure you do not use it in production code as it is vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Comment: Thank you dennis , but i don't want to accept any certificate . i need to validate the server's certificate