# Connect to a Server with Invalid Certificate using NSURLSession (swift2,xcode7,ios9)

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I'm using Xcode 7, Swift 2, and iOS9. I want to connect to a web service using NSURLSession but I get the following error when I try to connect:

```
2015-10-13 16:07:33.595 XCTRunner[89220:4520715] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2015-10-13 16:07:33.604 XCTRunner[89220:4520571] Error with connection, details: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “domainapi.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x7fac7b6facc0>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?,
```

Here is my code:

```
func request( dataPost : String, successHandler: (response: String) -> Void)-> String {
        let destination:String =  "https://domainapi.com:8743/WebService/sendData"
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: destination as String)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = dataPost
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.setValue("0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("gzip,deflate", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
        request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
        NSLog("Body is: %@", request.HTTPBody!)
        NSLog("Request is: %@", request.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
        NSLog("URL is: %@", destination)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in


            if error != nil {
                NSLog("Error with connection, details: %@", error!)
                return
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            successHandler(response: responseString as String!);
            NSLog("Data received: %@", data!)

        }

        task.resume()
        return "worked"
    }
    func viewDidLoad() {
        let dataPost : String = "<webservices>xml data sending</webservices>"
        request(dataPost, successHandler: {
            (response) in
            let text = response
            print(text)
        });
```

I've looked into `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` but I can't seem to figure that out with the code I currently have in place. So my question is how can I connect to the server anyway? I've already tried adding the domain to my `NSAppTransportSecurity` in Info.plist but that did not work. Turning on `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823

Comment: @ZoffDino that's using NSURLConnection which is deprecated in iOS8. I'd like to use NSURLSession if possible.

Comment: The AFNetworking library has excellent support for this, I would recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at this article.[Shipping an App With App Transport Security](http://timekl.com/blog/2015/08/21/shipping-an-app-with-app-transport-security/) particularly the sections about self-signed certificates.

You'll most likely need the delegate method of the form,

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(
        .UseCredential, 
        NSURLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
    )
}
```

Adding this to my own comms class that uses NSURLSession fixed the issue.

Comment: i added delegate but this method never called in swift 3, any other solutions without using alamofire or any other lib?

Answer (score 8):

When creating the URL Session, use the initializer, that sets the delegate along with the configuration, like below:

```
let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: urlSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Then, implement the following delegate method, it should work.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let urlCredential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
    completionHandler(.useCredential, urlCredential)
}
```

However, it is very important to note, that this is a security issue, and we should not be trying to connect to servers with invalid certificates.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the answers are almost there, but not quite. So here is what worked for me on Xcode 12.4

In my Requesting Class

```swift
    let session: URLSession
    let sessionDelegate: HTTPRequestDelegate
    private  init() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        // Some more configuration settings
        // ...

        sessionDelegate = HTTPRequestDelegate()
        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration,
                                 delegate:  sessionDelegate,
                                 delegateQueue: nil)
    }
```

Where:

```swift
public class HTTPRequestDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate
{
    // Get Challenged twice, 2nd time challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust is nil, but works!
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                    completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        print("In invalid certificate completion handler")
        if challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust != nil {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
        } else {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...! This answer is very useful and worked with me in Swift 5 and Xcode 13.1.

Comment: HI @chughts, tried the solution and it worked for me too, but is this the secure approach, as the api is secure with https

Comment: I think the problem occurs when using self signed certificates. In a production environment you won't be using self signed certificates.

Answer (score 0):

open your info.plist as a source code
Add following:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
           <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
          <true/>
   </dict>
```

This should help.

Comment: I don't see how this helps, as you're really just bypassing the IP addresses that the app talks to and not anything to do with server certificates?

Comment: @Marcelo : NSAllowsArbitaryLoads key when set to true will allows access to all unsecured URLs. So what is the point of having CER file for security?

Answer (score 0):

I received the error "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "www.yoururl.com" which could put your confidential information at risk."

I solved this by having doing this in my httpclient file. The following code will ignore the authentication request completely.

```
var session: URLSession?

session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

private func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition) -> Void) {
            completionHandler(
                .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
            )
        }
```

Also not sure if it impacted the above but In my info.plist I had "Allow Transport Security Settings" & the child key-value option "Allow Arbitrary Loads" which I set to YES.

Answer (score -1):

For SWIFT 4:

```
func URLSession(session: URLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(
        .useCredential,
        URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
    )
}
```