# Xamarin IOS - HttpClient - API working on one iPad and not another

Tags: ios, ssl, xamarin, certificate

I am consuming an "https://www.******pi.********^$%.org.uk" which is working one iPAD and is not working another. I have the same configuration device (Software and Hardware). I am connected to same network.

API call has been done using HttpClient class. It is working completely fine in Android.

This API call works with some iPad and not working with some iPad having same OS and configuration.It is a random behavior on iOS Devices to come on any conclusion.

I am working on Xamarin Native and have tried following solutions but have not succeeded -

> https://medium.com/outsystems-engineering/installing-a-valid-certificate-on-a-dev-server-433e499260fe
>
> [Connect to a Server with Invalid Certificate using NSURLSession (swift2,xcode7,ios9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128240/connect-to-a-server-with-invalid-certificate-using-nsurlsession-swift2-xcode7-i)
>
> [Trust a self signed certificate using Httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664218/trust-a-self-signed-certificate-using-httpclient)
>
> System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
>   delegate { return true; };

Below is issue which I am getting -

> {System.Net.WebException: The certificate for this server is invalid.
>   You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be
>   “**&^&*^&*%^.*(&^*(&^*^*&.org.uk” which could put your confidential
>   information at risk. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Exception of
>   type 'Foundation.NSErrorException' was thrown.    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.12.0.4/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535
>   at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler+d__29.MoveNext ()
>   [0x001c3] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/5944/64fece5f/source/xamarin-macios/src/Foundation/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:202

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are all the devices using the same iOS version? Also I would add the code that you are using to your question (i.e. using a custom NSUrlSession with Xamarin's NSUrlSessionHandler, or ?....) Also have you directly used `NSUrlSession` instead of HttpClient to rule out Xamarin as the issue? In the end, avoiding self-signed certs all together is the way to go... SSL certs are available for free... ;-)

Comment: Check the date and time on your iPad.  If the clock is too skewed, then TLS negotiation will fail

Comment: @Sushi I have tried using NURLSession and it is not working.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have checked for that. That is correct

Answer (score 0):

"The certificate for this server is invalid."
You have to install a trusted certificate on the server.

Another option is to put this into the AppDelegate:
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`

It will effectively ignore the certificate validation process (but is not recommended for production!)

Comment: I have tried this also but I am getting the same error . I am using HTTPClient third party library.

Comment: Then research on how to install the correct certificates

Comment: Issue is not with Certificate. It works on perfect some iPads. If there is an issue with Certificate, it would not have worked. Also, it works on Windows machine in Internet Explorer.