# iOS App Transport Security exceptions not working

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I'm trying to connect to a self-signed HTTPS server on iOS 9.1.

I'm using :

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
```

And I get an error saying that the certificate is not valid:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "<French error saying the certificate is invalid" 
UserInfo=
   {NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x13c768140>, 
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=<French recovery suggestion asking if the user wants to connect anyway>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=<CFArray 0x13d82ffe0 [0x1a1242b68]>
```

I've tried adding all possible transport security exceptions, my current attempt is:

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>mydomain.org</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I've also tried `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` but even that doesn't work.
I have several .plist files (cocoapods and tests), I think it's in the correct one (App/Supporting Files/Info.plist).

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need add this at the end like this

```
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was an NSURLConnection problem, and not app transport.

For the records, and for those who may face the same problem, I've fixed it temporarily by calling a private method (**do not do this**):

```
+ (void)setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:(BOOL)allow forHost:(NSString*)host;
```

**This won't be accepted by Apple**. The real solution is with [delegate methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert/2033823#2033823), I'll edit this answer when we will work on this (my client is a "developer", so I used his option, he said we'll figure out later, and we're in a hurry...)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved issues using following steps

1. Open Project's plist file
2. Add a key "NSAppTransportSecurity" and on Type Dictionary
3. Add a inner key "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" as Boolean YES

[image]