# Can an SSL connection succeed if the client doesn't provide a client certificate in iOS?

Tags: ios, https, client-certificates, nsurlconnectiondelegate

Consider using an NSURLConnectionDataDelegate that is implementing `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`.

If the delegate receives an authentication challenge and the protectionSpace is `NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate` and instead of providing one simply does the following.

```
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

The server has two options.

1. If it wants to require the certificate, it can simply terminate the connection and the iOS NSURLConnection will raise the error `NSURLErrorClientCertificateRequired`.
2. If the server wants to continue, it can simply do so by not severing the connection and the delegate should receive another call to `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`.

I have not been able to concretely verify this hypothesis.  I suppose it's possible the iOS NSURL stack can get in the way as well.  But I'm looking for some kind of verification on the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install SSL certificate on your server and when you try to hit API. Then you should use https instead of http. Hope this help you...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of how SSL works.  But I'm referring to a very specific configuration on SSL/TLS where client authentication may or may not actually be required by the server.  There are a number of authentication appliances/DMZ controllers that can be configured this way.  What I'm saying is in the context of the server not requiring a valid client certificate (even though it asks for one), I believe the expected behavior for the server to continue the request, e.g. the NSURLConnection will not encounter a failure with error.

Comment: Someone given answer here. Please check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933331/how-to-use-nsurlconnection-to-connect-with-ssl-for-an-untrusted-cert?rq=1

Comment: That link relates to a server identity certificate that cannot be verified by the client.  This scenario I'm describing is more or less the other way around.  If the server asks for a client certificate during SSL handshake (not the norm in https).  Based on settings the https server may decided it's ok that the client didn't provide a client certificate or it may choose to continue the transaction even though the client provided an expired or unverifiable certificate.